# Why do we need eleven expandafters to expand four tokens in the right order?

Tags: tex-core, expansion

In Appendix D - Dirty Tricks Knuth gives an example of expanding four tokens in the right order by using `eleven` `\expandafter` commands. Here, is the code slightly adapted for to-morrow!

```
\tracingmacros=2  \tracingcommands=2
\def\z{M}
\def\Z{C}
\def\a{\z er}
\def\b{ry }
\def\c{\Z hr}
\def\d{ist}
\def\e{mas}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\b\expandafter\c\d \e

\bye
```

This is in plain TeX, so you need to run it with pdfTeX. Why do we need 11 expandafters? Is there a rule of thumb for this type of definitions?  How many do you need to expand five i.e, to expand `\e` also which I conveniently spaced out!

Comment: \expandafters tend to come in powers of two, minus one: one expandafter is "reach over token once", to reach over the token twice, you need thre:, the first jumps to the third, the third jumps over your token, leaving the second to jump over the second time, and so on.

Comment: could one define a \superexpandafter{n} that would expand to 2^n-1 \expandafter's?

Comment: @Yossi. Only to some extent. You can do this if it is the first thing which needs to get expanded, but imagine `\expandafter\SomeToken\superexpandafter{n}`. You can't get the `\superexpandafter` to work 'as expected' here, as it would require at least two expansions to continue the chain past `\SomeToken`.

Comment: @Yiannis: By the way, there's no need for the two `%`.

Comment: @Hendrik You right I edited them out!

Comment: @Yossi: If you post the question in your comment as a new question, then I think I do have an answer. (It's too long to put it here.)

Comment: @hendr: OK. will do.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**The short answer**

Don't think of 11, but of 7+3+1 `\expandafter`s. To also reach the `\e`, you'll need 15+7+3+1 `\expandafter`s. As Ulrich says in his comment, these number are `2^4-1`, `2^3-1` and so on.

**What does `\expandafter` do?**

The TeX primitive `\expandafter` steps over the token following it and once expands the next one. Since your macros `\b`, `\c` and `\d` don't take arguments, the code

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\b\expandafter\c\d\e
```

expands to

```
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\a
\expandafter\b\c "\d, once expanded" \e
```

and this in turn to

```
\expandafter\a\b "\c, once expanded" "\d, once expanded" \e
```

to finally yield

```
\a "\b, once expanded" "\c, once expanded" "\d, once expanded" \e
```

With your definition of `\a`, `\b` and `\c`, you don't need all these `\expandafter`s since those macros don't take any arguments. In fact, the above is an oversimplification: In the general case, if the macros do take arguments, the last line above would look somewhat like

```
\a \once{\b \once{\c \once{\d \e}}}
```

where `\once` is not a TeX command but should mean that the argument is expanded once, and the innermost expansion happens first, the outermost last. Here's a really stupid example:

```
\def\a#1.{#1}
\def\b#1:{#1.}
\def\c#1,{#1:}
\def\d{Hello world!,}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\b
\expandafter\c\d
\bye
\def
```

Firstly, `\c` replaces the `,` in `Hello world!,` with `:`. Secondly, `\b` replaces the `:` with `.`, and finally `\a` strips the `.`. In this example, all the `\expandafter`s are needed.

**What do `2^n-1` `\expandafter`s do?**

`2^1-1=1` `\expandafter` expands the stuff after the next token *once*, and by induction you easily see that `2^n-1` `\expandafter`s expand the stuff after the next token `n` times. Moreover, making this happen takes `n` expansion steps. Let's look again at your code, now from this point of view:

The first 7 `\expandafter`s expand the stuff after `\a` 3 times. Two of **these 3** expansion steps are needed to expand the 3 `\expandafter`s after `\a`; let's keep in mind that a last expansion step is missing. Before that last step, the 3 `\expandafter`s after `\a` expand the stuff after `\b` 2 times. The first expansion yields `\c \once{\d \e}` after the `\b`, the second one yields `\once{\c \once{\d \e}}`. This completes the description of two of **these 3** expansion steps. In the third of **these 3**, the stuff after `\a` is expanded one last time.

In TH's comment, the 3 `\expandafter`s expand the `\csname bar\endcsname` *twice*, thus yielding the expansion of `\bar`. Another important case is

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\mycommand\expandafter{\somecontrolsequence}
```

This defines `\mycommand` as `\somecontrolsequence`, *once expanded*.

Another stupid example:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\b\c
```

expands `\c` twice, thus expanding to something like

```
\a\b\twice{\c}
```

Comment: And sometimes `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\foo\csname bar\endcsname` is useful. That is, expand `\bar` once before `\foo` even though `\bar` is constructed using `\csname ... \endcsname`.

Comment: "As Ulrich says in **her** comment"

Answer (score 25):

To expand on the same theme as TH.'s comment to Hendrik's answer, when you must use lengthly `\expandafter` chains, you can exploit constructions like `\csname...\endcsname` (or,  in some contexts, `\number`) which completely expand things by placing the right number of `\expandafter`s just after/before the token you want to expand, e.g.

```
\csname macroone\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname\macrotwo
```

will be the same as `\macroone` followed by `\macrotwo` expanded two times.

To give a concrete example, suppose you have `\a\b\c\d\e` and want to expand `\e` three times, `\c` two times, and `\a`, `\b`, `\d` one time. With the `\csname...\endcsname` method, it would be (here, we store the result of expansion inside a `\temp` macro and then `\show` it to see clearly what was expanded; you need the three `\expandafter` in the `\def\temp` because the first token needs two expansions):

```
\def\a{a}
\def\b{b}
\def\c{\C}\def\C{c}
\def\d{d}
\def\e{\E}\def\E{\ee}\def\ee{e}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\csname a\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\csname b\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\csname c\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\csname d\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
\e
}
\show\temp

\csname @@end\endcsname\bye % to work with both plain and LaTeX
```

To compare, here's the same version with chains of `\expandafter`s:

```
\def\a{a}
\def\b{b}
\def\c{\C}\def\C{c}
\def\d{d}
\def\e{\E}\def\E{\ee}\def\ee{e}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\b
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\c
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\d
\e
}
\show\temp

\csname @@end\endcsname\bye % to work with both plain and LaTeX
```

Comment: I am going to read this carefully once the new year's wine has disappeared. In the meantime I take my hat off to you!

Comment: Ingenious idea! I've used it in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/can-one-define-a-superexpandaftern-that-would-expand-to-2n-1-expandafter/8117#8117) to define a "superexpandafter".