# Repeat command n times?

Tags: macros, programming

Is it possible to define a command, which repeats the following command n-times? Call it for example `\Repeat`, then

```
\Repeat[4] \command{...}
```

should be equivalent to

```
\command{...} \command{...} \command{...} \command{...}
```

Comment: Note that `\repeat` is already defined by LaTeX as end-macro for `\loop`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This can be done in an expandable form using `\csname`. I would personally use the 'pre-packed' version in [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\Repeat{4}{\command{...}}
\end{document}
```

---

For those who would code by hand, the basic approach (originally by David Kastrup, modified somewhat by the rest of the team) is

```
\catcode `\@ = 11\relax
\long\def\replicate#1{%
  \romannumeral
    \expandafter\replicate@first@aux\number#1%
      \endcsname
}
\long\def\replicate@first@aux#1{%
  \csname replicate@first@#1\replicate@aux
}
\chardef\rm@end=0 %
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@-\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end\NegativeReplication}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@0\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@1\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@2\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@3\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@4\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@5\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@6\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@7\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@8\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@first@9\endcsname
  #1{\rm@end #1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\def\replicate@aux#1{%
  \csname replicate@#1\replicate@aux
}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@\endcsname#1{\endcsname}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@0\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@1\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@2\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@3\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@4\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@5\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@6\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@7\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@8\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\expandafter\def\csname replicate@9\endcsname
  #1{\endcsname{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\catcode `\@ = 12\relax
\edef\test{\replicate{20}{abc}}
\show\test
\bye
```

In the `expl3` version, the `\number#1` is (effectively) replaced by `\number\numexpr#1\relax`, which allows the 'number' used to be a calculation. If you try a negative number, the deliberately-undefined control sequence raises an error as part of the expansion, rather than having some odd error later.

---

A second expandable approach is to use `\romannumeral`, for example

```
\catcode `\@ = 11\relax
\def\replicate#1{%
  \expandafter\replicate@aux\romannumeral\number #1000Q{}
}
\def\replicate@aux#1{\csname replicate@aux@#1\endcsname}
\long\def\replicate@aux@m#1Q#2#3{\replicate@aux#1Q{#2#3}{#3}}
\long\def\replicate@aux@Q#1#2{#1}
\edef\test{\replicate{5}{a}}
\show\test
\bye
```

This is clearer to code than the `\csname` approach, but is effectively a loop again and so gets *slow* for large numbers of repetitions.

Comment: Ah, I should have known that LaTeX3 is having something like this. I coded something by myself and just saw your post.

Comment: Note that while this seems like a overkill-approach, it should be (much?) more efficient than the simpler looping code proposed in other answers.

Comment: As @Will says, this approach scales well (I use it for testing purposes often with 100k repetitions).

Comment: The important point to notice about the code is that it replicates for each power of ten. So as the number gets very big, rather than lots of single repetitions each 'level' requires only one pass.

Comment: However, for _huge_ number of repetitions, since all the repetitions are held in TeX's memory, we can overflow it. A solution in that case is `\prg_replicate:nn {10000}{\prg_replicate:nn {10000}{...}}`. Not needed often.

Comment: @JosephWright Using your first solution, how could I define the number inside the `\Repeat` command by a user input? `\newcommand{\test}[1]{\Repeat{#1}{Test}}` does not work as `#1` is not recognized as number.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `\foreach`-command from PGF/TikZ.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\cmd}{-x-}
% to provide your syntax
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{% \repeat already defined
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,4}{\cmd}

\Repeat{6}{\cmd}
\end{document}
```

For more information see the [pgfmanual.pdf](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section 56, pp. 504 an following.

There’s also a *TeX-Way* see e.g. [this page](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/blog/2008/04/13/latex-variablen-if-abfragen-und-schleifen/#toc-loop-tex) (in german …)

Comment: `pgf`s `\foreach` has the drawback that the command is executed in a group, which might be a big problem or none at all depending on the application. BTW: there is no reason the write `{}` after `\cmd` inside the loop, except if you have it as a placeholder for a possible argument (then you should write it as `{...}` as the OP did).

Comment: @MartinScharrer There’s no special reason why I used the `{}`. You’re right an I edited my post. Could you please outline a situation where the `\foreach`-group causes problems?

Comment: All assignments done in the loop will be executed in their own local group, which could have serious side effects depending on the code. Because you never known what code the user will use it is best to avoid these situations.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thank’s. Maybe I remember that in case of getting problem with `\foreach`if not I’ll be back to ask here ;-)

Comment: I tried to place multiple tickets on a paper using the `ticket` package and the `\foreach` loop. It failed. All tickets are printed at the same location.

Comment: @Lemming: Your question is unlikely to be answered her, and I also thing it has not that much to do with this question or my answer. Please post a new question including a complete Minimal Working Example ;-)

Comment: @Tobi It was no question but an answer. You asked for a situation where the implementation of `\foreach` could cause problems and I gave you such a situation that I encountered in real life. The solution in my case was `multido` as suggested in another answer. I may edit my comment in order to make my intention clearer.

Answer (score 12):

[`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido) has a simple interface for replication:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand{\cmd}{-x-}
\newcommand{\Repeat}{\multido{\i=1+1}}
\begin{document}

\Repeat{6}{\cmd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an old answer, but I want just to mention that `\i=1+1` is useless here, `\newcommand{\Repeat}{\multido{}}` is enough.

Answer (score 7):

Here some implementation I came up with which doesn't need any extra package. It uses `\numexpr` to avoid counters and is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Repeat}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@Repeat\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1\relax}%
}

\def\@Repeat#1{%
    \ifnum#1>0
        \expandafter\@@Repeat\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
    \else
        \expandafter\@gobble
    \fi
}
\def\@@Repeat#1#2{%
    \@Repeat{#1}{#2}#2%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Repeat{0}{test }

\Repeat{1}{test }

\Repeat{2}{test }

\Repeat{3}{test }

\Repeat{4}{test }

\Repeat{5}{test }

\edef\TEST{\Repeat{5}{test }}
\texttt{\meaning\TEST}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you look at the LaTeX3 implementation, it's expandable even without needing e-TeX. This is some clever code that has been around for many years.

Comment: @Joseph: I have a really hard time reading the `expl3` code, but it looks like it needs e-TeX to me. It uses `\int_eval:w` a.k.a. `\numexpr`.

Comment: @TH. The `expl3` implementation does indeed need `\numexpr`, as that makes the nature of the 'number' you give be more flexible. However, the original version of this approach just uses `\number`, and thus no e-TeX. Later on today I'll post the code 'translated' to plain TeX as a separate answer.

Comment: @TH. I've added the plain TeX code to my answer, avoiding e-TeX but explaining why it is used for the `expl3` version.

Comment: @Joseph: I see now, that's very clever! Thanks. (One of these days, I really just need to learn `expl3`.)

Comment: @JosephWright This code (using nested `\csname`s) is not so clever (IMHO) because there is redundant ``\romannumeral-`0`` and more redundant `\expandafter`s before each `\long` primitive.

Comment: @wipet I've updated the code, first to remove the unneeded `\expandafter` (a re-writing oversight) and second to adjust where the `\romannumeral` is so it's doing what was intended.

Comment: @JosephWright the code of `expl3` is very clever and seems hard to beat. A variant can be coded more compactly, but less efficiently, using `\numexpr` to divide by 2  (as we don't have access bitwise to computer  words must go via division by 2 and oddness checks). Perhaps it could be pointed out that apart from speed it also avoids the input save stack problem which the "linear" approach as in Martin's code , which leaves upstream one copy at a time, necessarily hits. (this is why I am leaving my comment here...). (one can modify the code here to deliver only at the end, but this is slower).

Answer (score 6):

Plain and simple (pun intended):

```
\def\foo{keke}
\def\bar#1#2{\count0=#1 \loop \ifnum\count0>0 \advance\count0 by -1 #2\repeat}
\bar3\foo % results in kekekekekeke
\bye
```

Token list registers expand more quickly, so if it suits you, you could also do:

```
\newtoks\foo \foo={keke}
\def\bar#1#2{\count0=#1 \loop \ifnum\count0>0 \advance\count0 by -1 \the#2\repeat}
\bar3\foo % results in kekekekekeke
\bye
```

Repeating in an expendable way using e-tex additions (from http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92jackowski.pdf):

```
\def\foo{keke}
\def\gobbleone#1{}
\long\def\replicate#1#2{% 
  \ifnum\numexpr#1>0 
    #2\expandafter\replicate\expandafter 
    {\number\numexpr#1-1\expandafter}% 
  \else 
    \expandafter\gobbleone 
  \fi{#2}}
\replicate3\foo % results in kekekekekeke
\bye
```

Comment: Yes, but not expandable. Ok, it isn't really necessary in the majority of the cases.

Comment: What does it mean not being _expandable_?

Comment: Christian forgot to notify @Martin I guess, since I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: @Christian: Something is _expandable_ if you can use it inside an `\edef` or `\write` an TeX converts it fully to what you want. Assignments are not expandable, and so a loop using a count will not turn into a series of repeated commands inside an `\edef`.

Comment: @Christian: I thought that the general question had been asked, but cannot find it. You might wish to ask about expandability in general, and those of us who understand it can try to explain!

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for your explanation, it gets the general idea across. You might have thought about [Tricks to Make Macros Expandable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/tricks-to-make-macros-expandable) which discusses this property.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, the simple answer to the OP is: use `\loop`. But there are more codes here signed as "clever", if the loop is done only at expand processor level. And more "clever" codes here do this without using of eTeX primitives.

So, I give two codes here. You can explore them from "cleverness" point of view:).

First code uses known trick with `\romannumeral #1000` which expands to #1 "em"s and then we do loop over these "em"s over input stream. The main difference from the similar code presented here by @Joseph is that we needn't to read whole long sequence of "em"s again and again:

```
\def\replicate#1{\expandafter\repU\expandafter{\romannumeral\number#1000}}
\def\repU#1#2{\repV{#2}#1;}
\def\repV#1#2{\ifx#2;\else#1\fihere\repV{#1}\fi}
\def\fihere#1\fi{\fi#1}

\message{\replicate{27}{abc}}
\bye
```

The second code is inspired by second code presented here by @Joseph where each decimal digit is processed individually. The code (in the accepted answer) uses nested `\csname`s. I do the same without nested `\csname`s and the code is more compact. Of course, it works at expand processor level without any need of eTeX primitives:

```
\def\replicate#1{\expandafter\repA\number#1;;}
\def\repA#1#2;#3;{\ifx;#2;\repB#1#3\fi \repA#2;#1#3;}
\def\repB#1\fi#2;#3;{\fi\repC{#1}}
\def\repC#1#2{\repD{#2}#1;}
\def\repD#1#2{\ifx#2;\else \repE{#1}#2\fi}
\def\repE#1#2\fi{\fi \repF#2{#1}\repD{\repF{10}{#1}}}
\def\repF#1#2{\ifcase#1 \or#2\or#2#2\or#2#2#2\or#2#2#2#2\or#2#2#2#2#2\or
   #2#2#2#2#2#2\or#2#2#2#2#2#2#2\or#2#2#2#2#2#2#2#2\or
   #2#2#2#2#2#2#2#2#2\or#2#2#2#2#2#2#2#2#2#2\fi}

\message{\replicate{27}{abc}}
\bye
```

Comment: My comment about eTeX was probably misleading: I've removed it (you need eTeX if you want to accept integer expressions for the number of repeats, not for the core idea of making copies).

Comment: nice but it should be pointed out this doesn't expand fully under ``\romannumeral-`0``.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with *loop* and *newcommand*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{z}
\newcommand\y[2]{
  \loop \ifnum\value{z} < #1
    #2%
    \stepcounter{z}%
  \repeat
}
\begin{document}
\y{10}{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The request is to repeat a _command_

Comment: Only the simplest commands - e.g. if the new command defines other commands the grouping is not equivalent.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the first suggestion in @morbusg's answer?

Answer (score 2):

I tried an alternative to the clever `\csname` governed expansion from Joseph's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16192/4686) borrowed from expl3 code.

eTeX is used only to allow input to be an expression: else replace `\the\numexpr` at the start by `\number`.

This is less efficient than the David Kastrup + LaTeX team code, although perhaps it becomes about the same when the number of replications is in the thousands (not much tested).

The initial version of this answer had more complicated code which was at about the same level of efficiency. There was an unfortunate `\chardef\z@=0` in that code, which is very wrong and I don't know why it was there.

This answer handles more efficiently than Joseph's the case of a negative asked for number of replication.

It could be easily reworked into a macro (working only in a `\edef`) leaving tokens behind it rather than in front of it while expanding.

```
\catcode`@ 11

\def\JFsignfork #10-#2#3\krof {#2}
%\chardef\z@ 0 % NO! \z@ is a dimen in TeX/LaTeX

\def\JFrep   #1{\romannumeral\expandafter\JFrep@a\the\numexpr #1;3456789XY!}%
\def\JFrep@a #1{\JFsignfork
                  #1-\JFrep@nil
                  0#1\JFrep@neg
                   0-\JFrep@b
              \krof #1%
             }%
\long\def\JFrep@nil #1!#2{\z@}
\long\def\JFrep@neg #1!#2{\z@\NegativeReplication}

% TeX numbers have at most 10 digits
\def\JFrep@b #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\JFrep@c {.#9.#8.#7.#6.#5.#4.#3.#2;#1}}
\def\JFrep@c #1#2#3#4!{\JFrep@d .#3.#2#1!}
\def\JFrep@d #1;#2#3{\csname JFrep@f#2#3\endcsname}
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.0\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.1\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.2\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.3\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.4\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.5\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.6\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.7\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.8\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f.9\endcsname #1#2#3!#4%
     {\csname JFrep@f#1#2\endcsname#3!{#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;1\endcsname!#1{\z@#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;2\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;3\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;4\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;5\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;6\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1#1#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;7\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;8\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}%
\long\expandafter\def\csname JFrep@f;9\endcsname!#1{\z@#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}%

\catcode`@ 12

\edef\test{\JFrep{123}{abc}}
\show\test

\bye
```

Comment: There is now an `\xintreplicate` in [xint](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/org) but it is a clone of the expl3's code with very minor changes, it is not the code of this answer...