# How to define a parshape command with LaTeX?

Tags: macros, indentation, paragraphs, loops

I want to typeset a book with some `\parshape` command, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\parshape=4
0.2\textwidth 0.8\textwidth
0.2\textwidth 0.8\textwidth
0.2\textwidth 0.8\textwidth
0pt \textwidth
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

But since the lines and width may changes frequently, so I want to define a command like this

```
\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{0}
\newcommand{\MyParShape}[3]
{
\parshape=#1
\loop
#2\textwidth #3\textwidth 
\addtocounter{foo}{1}
\if\thefoo<#1-1\repeat
0pt \textwidth
}
```

So I can call it like

```
\MyParShape{5}{0.5}{0.5}
```

or

```
\MyParShape{10}{0.8}{0.2}
```

But this does not work, I'm not an expert of TeX primitives, can somebody help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Harald says, the key here is that you need everything expanded. You can do that in a temporary variable, as he shows. Alternatively, you can use something like an expandable '[repeat *n* times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/repeat-command-n-times)' approach. Here, I'm assuming e-TeX is available

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\replicate[1]{%
  \expandafter\replicate@aux\romannumeral\number\numexpr #1\relax000Q{}
}
\newcommand*\replicate@aux[1]{\csname replicate@aux@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\replicate@aux@m{}
\long\def\replicate@aux@m#1Q#2#3{\replicate@aux#1Q{#2#3}{#3}}
\newcommand\replicate@aux@Q[2]{#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\MyParShape[3]{%
    \parshape = #1
      \replicate{#1 -1}{#2\textwidth #3\textwidth}%
      0pt\textwidth
}
\newcommand*\my@parshape{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\MyParShape{3}{0.6}{0.4}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the paragraph shape you need is like that, it's simpler to obtain it with

```
\hangindent=.2\textwidth \hangafter=-3
```

Comment: Excellent point! That is why I chose a more complicated example in my answer, but I should have made it explicit.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your approach doesn't work is that it does not expand fully in TeX's mouth. Now building a fully expandable version might be rather involved. An easier approach is probably to first build up a command sequence containing your finished `\parshape` and the executing that. In the following complete example I use a token register:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtoks\pstoks
\newcounter{pscnt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\parshapestart}[1]{\pstoks{\parshape=#1 }}
\newcommand{\parshapeappend}[1]{\pstoks\expandafter{\the\pstoks#1}}
\newcommand{\parshapeadd}[3]
  {
    \setcounter{pscnt}{0}
    \loop
    \parshapeappend{#2\textwidth #3\textwidth}
    \addtocounter{pscnt}{1}
    \ifnum\c@pscnt<#1\repeat
  }
\newcommand{\parshapeend}[1][0pt \textwidth]
  {\parshapeappend{#1}\the\pstoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parshapestart{6}
\parshapeadd{3}{0.2}{0.8}
\parshapeadd{2}{0.1}{0.9}
\parshapeend
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can avoid the counter by using an expandable repetition routine, as seen in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/repeat-command-n-times. My first approach was to do that inside an `\edef`, but as you posted a similar answer I've gone for avoiding additional storage and using full expansion!

Answer (score 2):

For LaTeX (and plainTeX) there is the [`shapepar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shapepar) package which provides a set of predefined shapes but also allows you to define your own. However, it doesn't solve the issue with the unexpandable loop for you.

> The command `\shapepar` should be used at the beginning of a paragraph,
>   and it applies to the entire paragraph. There is one optional length parameter:
>   a fixed scale, `<scale len>`; and one required parameter: a description of the shape, `<shape spec>`.
>
> ```
> \shapepar [<scale len>]{<shape spec>} Text of the paragraph
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcount\shapectr
\newcommand\myParShape[3]{%
  \shapectr=0
  \def\shapeLength{}
  \loop
    \edef\shapeLength{\shapeLength #2\textwidth #3\textwidth }
    \advance\shapectr by 1
    \ifnum\the\shapectr<#1\relax
  \repeat
  \expandafter\parshape\numexpr #1+1\relax  
  \shapeLength
  0pt \textwidth%
}

\begin{document}
\myParShape{3}{0.2}{0.8}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```