# Macros just for certain number of lines

Tags: macros, formatting

I want to write a macro that will do certain things with a fixed number of lines coming after this macro.

For example, how to apply `\rightskip=2cm` to the first four lines of a paragraph

How to write a macro that will know some of the commands like `\rightskip`,`\bfseries` and the number of lines which it should affect with these commands?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to be a lot more specific about what you need. You can affect the length of the lines for initial lines in a paragraph using `\parshape`. You can not change `\rightskip` in the way you suggest as that is a parameter set for the whole paragraph based on the value at the end. TeX does not break lines line-by-line it does a least cost optimisation of linebreaking over a paragraph _after_ all macros in that paragraph have been expanded.

Answer (score 4):

## Shape of paragraph

The geometry of a paragraph can be configured with `\parshape`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\parshape 5 % five pairs of settings for the left and right indent of a line
0pt \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax % first line
0pt \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax
0pt \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax
0pt \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax % fourth line
0pt \linewidth                   % remaining lines
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with truncated first four lines]

See also the answers for question [How to define a parshape command with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18121/how-to-define-a-parshape-command-with-latex) for more comfortable solutions.

## Font changes

There isn't an easy solution for font changes. There is a problem with circular dependencies: The paragraph builder needs to know the fonts in order to know the width of the text components to break the paragraph into lines. However, making the first four lines bold is not possible anymore at this stage; also
the width would change and the lines would be too long.

### Manual solution

First the paragraph is set in bold, the document compiled and the result is inspected to get the break point between the forth and fifth line. With the hyphenation pattern for `latin`, its after the word `Pellentesque`.
When the font is changed for the text of the first four lines, it might be possible, that the paragraph builder might find different break points. Therefore the the following example closes the paragraph, forcing the last
line to fill the full line width. Then a new paragraph is added without additional vertical space and suppressed paragraph indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begingroup
    \bfseries
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque%
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%
    \par
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \noindent
  \endgroup
  habitant morbi tristique
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut
  leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
  fringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
  placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
  nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
  Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
  Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis
  nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
  eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with first four lines in bold font]

Comment: I knew about `\parshape` in this way like you did it.

I am talking about such ideal command like `\doit{\parshape 1
0pt \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax}{4}`, where 4 - number of lines...

But thanks to you. Now I guess that it is impossible for my desire to be true.

Comment: @Dida See [How to define a parshape command with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18121/how-to-define-a-parshape-command-with-latex)

Comment: I saw it. Unfortunally, all tryings to copypaste it lead to the following: http://shot.qip.ru/00PIKb-5oHGoulrt/

Comment: @Dida The answers explain the method. Of course, you have to adjust the parameters to your needs.