# Beamer: including items only some slides using a relative syntax

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am looking for the syntax for making an item appear on say the next three slides. I'm imagining something like

```
\item<+-??>
```

The `\item` should appear here and disappears 3 slides later, in the same way it would if I used `\only` (*i.e.* the item shouldn't leave any space once it vanishes).

I'm illustrating this using `\item`, but I'm looking for a general syntax.

Comment: Just write `\item<+-.(3)> my item`. The topic is intensely covered by the great answer of Joseph to [Relative overlay specifications in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer), which appears to be a duplicate of this question. Please take a look at it, if you agree we could close this question.

Comment: I agree. Sorry, I red this answer before, because of lak of english or of attention, I didn't understand that it was THE answer ;-)

Comment: @Tarass Based on the comments on the answer here, it seems you want a solution which doesn't just 'hide' but completely 'ignores' one or more `\item` lines using a relative spec. That's related to the link suggested by Daniel but not a dupe. Could you clarify the question? If I'm right, there is a solution related to my answer in the link, but it's a not quite the same.

Comment: It was a `mwe` what I exactly wanted is the syntax to deal with an overlay between current position and 3 slides later. Then I cas use it with `\only`, `\visible`, `\invisible` ... it depends. I just looked for the syntax, (Daniel gave it to me and the link to your answer) for me it is a duplicate question as suggested and I marked so. Sorry for my poor english. But it is not a duplicate, and because of an english suptility I can express, please fill free to clarify my question. Thank you for your concern and for your answer. Btw I use it in tikzpicture not with items.

Comment: I've edited here and removed the dupe, based on the (now deleted) comments on [dcmst's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205657).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [Relative overlay specification in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer) I covered how to use relative specifications, but there I stuck to the visible/invisible switch. What you want is the 'extended' syntax which also allows things like altering on some slides or (here) applying `\only`-like effects:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<+-> item 1
      \item<+-> item 2
      \item<only@+-.(3)> item 3
      \item<+-> item 4
      \item<+-> item 5
      \item<+-> item 6
   \end{itemize}

   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The key here is that `only@` prefix to the 'standard' relative specification, which switches it from doing the normal 'visible/invisible' action to the 'only' action. The part after the `@` is exactly the same idea as described in my other answer.

Comment: Perhaps I'll mention this in my blog!

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what wanted. If one omit `only@`, one has the `\visible` behavior. Great !

Comment: http://www.texdev.net/2014/10/13/beamer-overlays-beyond-the-visible/

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to create your own macro, something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mytimeditem}[1]{\only<+>{\item #1}\only<+>{\item #1}\only<+>{\item #1}}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<+-> item 1
      \item<+-> item 2
      \mytimeditem{item 3}
      \item<+-> item 4
      \item<+-> item 5
      \item<+-> item 6
   \end{itemize}

   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to leave a blank line where "item 3" was, replace the last `\only` into `\mytimeditem` with `\onslide`

Second version:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mytimeditem}[1]{\only<+>{\item #1}\only<+>{\item #1}\only<+>{\item #1}\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-2}}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<+-> item 1
      \item<+-> item 2
      \mytimeditem{item 3}
      \item<+-> item 4
      \item<+-> item 5
      \item<+-> item 6
   \end{itemize}

   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### A more generic version

With `expl3` (code from [@Joseph Wright answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16192/24483)) and `calc`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\timeditem}[2]{
 \Repeat{#1}{
   \only<+>{\item #2}
 }\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-#1+1}
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<+-> item 1
      \item<+-> item 2
      \timeditem{4}{item 3}
      \item<+-> item 4
      \item<+-> item 5
      \item<+-> item 6
      \item<+-> item 7
   \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now the relative number of repetitions can be specified on the fly and the number of `pause`s is automatically adjusted.

[image]

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I don't want a stop for 3 slide on this item, I want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... smooth but 3 disapears after 5.

Comment: @Tarass, see the edit.

Comment: Thank for all your work, but Joseph Wright gives the general compact syntax that answers the question he expresses better than me. I must accept his answer.

Comment: @Tarass I completely agree :)