# How to avoid the compilation of some of my newcommands in latex

Tags: macros, comments

I'm writing an exam for my students, and have defined 3 commands to insert spaces with `\dotfill` permitting them to write their responses: `\rep`,`\replarge`, `\repLarge` for short and large responses:

```
\newcommand{\rep}{\noindent \dotfill 

 \noindent\dotfill

\noindent\dotfill

\noindent\dotfill

}
\newcommand{\repshort}\rep \rep 

\newcommand{\repLarge}\rep \rep \rep \rep
```

So, my questions are:

1. is there any way to ameliorate those commands?
2. how can I produce two pdf versions when compiling: One with the spaces produced with the commands, and the other without the spaces?

Comment: For (1), see [Repeat command n times?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16189/5764)

Comment: Before you implement too much on this, see if [the exam class](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) will suffice for any or all of your needs. Section 7 of the documentation shows several ways to leave space for answers, and section 8 covers printing solutions for a grading key or similar.

Comment: If you want to implement (2) yourself, wrap the body of `rep` in a `toggle` from the `etoolbox` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one quick and dirty solution to the second question and a link to more advanced solutions (the comments above also contain useful links for both questions):

a) Create two main files where you (1) provide the commands with the spaces and (2) provide the same commands as empty commands (you can also just append something like `\renewcommand{\rep}{}` and comment this in or out).

OR

b) Use parameters for your document and use a Makefile. Look at the answers to [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) for some inspiration. Here is an example of how such a Makefile could look like and how your .tex file can make use of it:

Makefile:

```
default: Exercise.pdf Solution.pdf

Exercise.pdf: *.tex
    -rm Exercise.pdf
    pdflatex -file-line-error --jobname=Exercise '\def\isexercise{1} \input{main.tex}'
    pdflatex -file-line-error --jobname=Exercise '\def\isexercise{1} \input{main.tex}'

Solution.pdf: *.tex
    -rm Solution.pdf
    pdflatex -file-line-error --jobname=Solution '\input{main.tex}'
    pdflatex -file-line-error --jobname=Solution '\input{main.tex}'
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\rep}{}

\ifdefined\isexercise
  \renewcommand{\rep}{
        \noindent\dotfill 

        \noindent\dotfill

        \noindent\dotfill

        \noindent\dotfill
  }
\fi

\begin{document}

Exercise 1: \rep

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Cryingshadow for the response, but I am a trully poor user of windows$, I think that the Makefile doesn't work with the windows$ system.

Comment: Use Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/).