# Exam with multiple choice using exsheets

Tags: exam, exsheets

I have seen many examples of multiple choice exams setting the correct with `exam`. But, is there anyway of doing a mulitple choice with `exsheets`?

I would like something like:

```
1. Question 1
  a)
  b)
  c)
```

And then in the code have something that sets bold the correct answer when I toggle it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `exsheets` strictly separates questions from solutions, the only way that adheres to this separation would be something like copying an enumeration environment and marking the correct answer with `\textbf` in the solution. Using the `\PrintSolutionsTF` command does not work inside the question environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[type=exam]
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item answer 1
\item answer 2
\item answer 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item answer 1
\item \textbf{answer 2}
\item answer 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}[type=exam]
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item answer 1
% does not work as this is not in a solution environment
\item \PrintSolutionsTF{\textbf{answer 2}}{answer 2}
\item answer 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

You could, however, define your own commands to achieve your desired behavior. This would then be independent of the package. See [How to avoid the compilation of some of my newcommands in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219306/how-to-avoid-the-compilation-of-some-of-my-newcommands-in-latex/219311#219311) for such a solution.

Answer (score 9):

Below I provide:

- An answer to your original question, how to make the correct choice appear bold.
- What I prefer to do: print just the answer in a separate "Answers" section, without repeating the entire question.

I'll start with my preferred method.

---

### What I Prefer

**Edit**: original version of this code was missing a `%`, which ended up putting extra whitespace before the correct answer. That would be undesirable!

Here we define a command `\correct` using `\PrintSolutionsTF{<true code>}{<false code>}` that:

- When inside a question, marks its location with a label `\label{ans:\CurrentQuestionID}`.
- When inside a solution, references `\ref{ans:\CurrentQuestionID}`.

This requires the `auto-label` option for `exsheets`.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets}

\newcommand{\correct}{
    \PrintSolutionsTF{%
        \ref{ans:\CurrentQuestionID}%
        }{%
        \label{ans:\CurrentQuestionID}%
        }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    Which letter is a vowel?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task \correct A
        \task B
        \task C
        \task D
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \correct
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    Which animal is the best?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task cats
        \task dogs
        \task \correct honey badgers
        \task dragons
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \correct
\end{solution}

\section*{Answers}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

### What you originally asked for

Mark the correct option `\correct`, and the `etoolbox` command `\ifstrequal` switches that option to bold if `\ShowAnswers` has value `true`. (This requires expanding `\ShowAnswers` before `\ifstrequal` is evaluated. See [Comparing an argument to a string when argument is a result of a command with etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/comparing-an-argument-to-a-string-when-argument-is-a-result-of-a-command-with-et) )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\ShowAnswers}{false}
\renewcommand{\ShowAnswers}{true} %comment this out if you do not want to show the answers
\newcommand{\correct}{%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\ShowAnswers}{true}{\bfseries}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    Which letter is a vowel?
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task \correct A
        \task B
        \task C
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Which animal is the best?
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task cats
        \task \correct honey badgers
        \task dragons
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Outputs

[image]

Comment: Does this not work in document class exam?

Comment: Could you look at this problem?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699607/making-multiple-choice-problems-through-exsheets-package/699611#699611