# elsarticle: Changing symbol used in \tnoteref

Tags: symbols, footnotes, titles, elsarticle

In the `elsarticle` class, when you use the command `\tnoteref`, a star is placed at the end of the title and used as the symbol for the footnote, see the example below.

I would like to change that to something other than a star, say a dagger.  Is there a way to do that by adding code to a `.tex` file's preamble?

```
    \documentclass{elsarticle}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
    \title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}}
    \author{M. Author}
    \tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
    \end{frontmatter}
    \section{Paper Material}
    Some Text.
    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Due to changes in* `elsarticle` *since this answer was first posted, the approach now depends on the package version.*

**For version 3.1 (January 2019)**

Since version 1.2, the package replaced `\ding{73}` with `$\star$` for title footnotes and changed its approach to handling the footnote index. Also, a new package option (`doubleblind`) was added and the title footnotes disabled if it is used.

The following is a reimplementation of the original "for fun" edit below that removes the two footnote limit and replaces the default symbol with the user-defined `\tnotemarksymbol`.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\ifdoubleblind\else%The default behavior is to disable title footnotes for doubleblind reviews (the edit will fail if applied with the doubleblind option)
    \patchcmd{\tnotetext}{\ifcase\c@tnote\or$\star$\or$\star\star$\fi}{\Repeat{\the\c@tnote}{\tnotemarksymbol}}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\tnotetext}}
    \patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\expandafter\ifcase\elsRef{\mytmark}\or$^{\star}$\or$^{,\star\star}$\fi}{\textsuperscript{\expandafter\ifnum\elsRef{\mytmark}>1,\fi\expandafter\Repeat\expandafter{\elsRef{\mytmark}}{\tnotemarksymbol}}}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\tnotemark}}%
\fi
\makeatother
\newcommand{\tnotemarksymbol}{\dag}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
        \title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}\tnoteref{t2}\tnoteref{t3}\tnoteref{t4}}
        \author{M. Author}
        \tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
        \tnotetext[t2]{Another title note.}
        \tnotetext[t3]{One more title note.}
        \tnotetext[t4]{Yet another title note.}
    \end{frontmatter}
    \section{Paper Material}
    Some Text.
\end{document}
```

**Original answer: For Version 1.2 and (possibly) 3.0**

You can patch the `\tnotemark` and `\tnotetext` commands with `etoolbox` to replace the star (`\ding{73}`) with the dagger (`\dag`):

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    %replace first instance (first tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\ding{73}}{\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotemark\space for \string\ding{73}}}
    %replace second instance (second tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\ding{73}\ding{73}}{\dag\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotemark\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}
    %replace first instance (first tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotetext}{\ding{73}}{\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotetext\space for \string\ding{73}}}
    %replace second instance (second tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotetext}{\ding{73}\ding{73}}{\dag\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotetext\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}\tnoteref{t2}}
\author{M. Author}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
\tnotetext[t2]{Another title note.}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**Edit:**

For fun, here is a generalization of the `\tnotemark`/`\tnotetext` system used by `elsarticle` for more than 2 notes. It uses `expl3` ([specifically this answer by Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16192/89497)) to repeat the symbol defined by the command `\tnotemarksymbol` by the count associated with each note.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\tnotetext}{\ifcase\c@tnote\or\ding{73}\or\ding{73}\ding{73}\fi}{\Repeat{\the\c@tnote}{\tnotemarksymbol}}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\tnotetext}}
    \patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\ifcase\tnotenum\or\ding{73}\or,\ding{73}\ding{73}\fi}{\ifnum\tnotenum>1,\fi\Repeat{\tnotenum}{\tnotemarksymbol}}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\tnotemark}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\tnotemarksymbol}{\dag}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}\tnoteref{t2}\tnoteref{t3}\tnoteref{t4}}
\author{M. Author}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
\tnotetext[t2]{Another title note.}
\tnotetext[t3]{One more title note.}
\tnotetext[t4]{Yet another title note.}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Hopefully you have only one `\tnoteref`...

Comment: @Werner: Generalized to the apparent maximum of two (the native `elsarticle` doesn't add a symbol after the second `\tnoteref`).

Comment: This solution worked perfectly until recently. Executing this code now throws the following error: "Argument of \@latex@error has an extra }. ...\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}"

Comment: @AK16: I have added a workaround for the recent changes to `elsarticle`.

Answer (score 3):

[`elsarticle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) uses `\ding{73}` to place the notes inside the title, as is identified by the macros `\tnoteref` and `\tnotetext` inside [`elsarticle.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle.dtx):

```
\def\tnotemark[#1]{\textsuperscript{\@for\@@tmark:=#1\do{%
      \edef\tnotenum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@tmark}{1}{\elsRef{\@@tmark}}}%
      \ifcase\tnotenum\or\ding{73}\or,\ding{73}\ding{73}\fi}}%
\def\tnotetext[#1]#2{\g@addto@macro\@tnotes{%
  \refstepcounter{tnote}\elsLabel{#1}%
   \def\thefootnote{\ifcase\c@tnote\or\ding{73}\or\ding{73}\ding{73}\fi}%
    \footnotetext{#2}}}
```

You can intervene here and condition on whether `\ding{<num>}` is supplied with `73` or otherwise:

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\let\oldding\ding% Make a copy of \ding called \oldding
% Update \ding to condition on 73 or otherwise
\renewcommand{\ding}[1]{\ifnum#1=73 $\star$\else\oldding{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}}
\author{M. Author}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.

\end{document}
```

This takes care of whether or not you use one or two `\tnote...`s inside `\title` (but removes the capability to use `\ding{73}` elsewhere).