# acknowledgments in elsevier journal format

Tags: elsarticle

Im writing a paper using the elsarticle.cls. I want to write the acknowledgments part. There is a specific command for that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There is nothing like that in `elsarticle.cls` (nothing that matches the search `ack`, at least). I always use `\section*{acknowledgements}`.

Comment: I think you can youse \tnoteref{t1}, see here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283479/elsarticle-changing-symbol-used-in-tnoteref

Answer (score 9):

You should code it as an unnumbered section, i.e. `\section*{Acknowledgement}`.

**Source**

This answer comes from a [FAQ for elsarticle.cls](https://web.archive.org/web/20201014172226/https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ_-_elsarticle.cls). The FAQ is hosted by [stmDOCS](https://web.archive.org/web/20201016213159/https://www.stmdocs.in/), which is connected to Elsevier in the following way.

Elsevier uses [Neptune](https://web.archive.org/web/20201014172049/https://neyyar.stmdocs.org:28443/neptunedocs/neptune-liveR1905/neptune-userguide.html), which is 'a web-based proofing framework for LaTeX authors. It is part of [TEXFolio](https://web.archive.org/web/20201016213313/https://texfolio.org/), the complete journal production system in the cloud' (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201016213355/https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-2/tb125rajendran-neptune.pdf)). In turn, TEXFolio is part of stmDOCS (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201016213429/https://www.stmdocs.in/texfolio.html)).

Now, in the FAQ, under 'Main matter', we find question 7:

> How can I create an acknowledgement section?

The answer, reproduced [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200818212803/https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Ans._M7), is

> It should be coded as an unnumbered section. For example: `<geshi lang="latex">`
>
> `\section*{Acknowledgement}`
>
> `</geshi>`

The `geshi` parts are presumably not part of the answer. GeSHi stands for 'Generic Syntax Highlighter' (as their [website explains](https://web.archive.org/web/20201016213522/http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html), 'As long as you have a language file for almost any computer language - whether it be a scripting language, object orientated, markup or anything in between - GeSHi can highlight it').