# Use (IIII) rather than (IV) in enumeration with roman numerals

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Using the package `enumitem` I can edit my enumerations to use roman numerals, so that

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textsc{\textsc(\roman*)}]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{enumerate}
```

yields the expected

```
(I) A
(II) B
(III) C
(IV) D
```

but in computer modern with nice formatting bits. How can I change this so that (IV) becomes (IIII) instead?

Comment: Interesting to know would also be what you would like to do with a.o. `V`, `VI`, `VII`, `VIII`, `IX`, `X`

Comment: Might be valid for some clocks (I don't see a reference to a clock in the question though), but this looks like a more general question to me.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik, Not quite. Some clocks also use VIIII in lieu of IX

Comment: The point is that even if your assumption is true about this being about clocks, your suggestion that we don't ask for further info should not be considered.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change `\roman` everywhere to that style then

```
\makeatletter
\def\@roman#1{\ifnum#1=4 iiii\else\romannumeral #1\fi}
\makeatother
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300215/36296, you could something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcount\my@repeat@count
\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \my@repeat@count=\z@
  \@whilenum\my@repeat@count<#1\do{#2\advance\my@repeat@count\@ne}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}[label={(\textsc{\protect\myrepeat{\value*}{I}})}]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]