# Repeat characters n times to fill the current line

Tags: loops, textwidth

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300215), someone provides a macro for repeating a string a given number of times. Here's a minimal working example of that macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\my@repeat@count
\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \my@repeat@count=\z@
  \@whilenum\my@repeat@count<#1\do{#2\advance\my@repeat@count\@ne}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myrepeat{3}{a}

\myrepeat{6}{b}

\myrepeat{9}{c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am using this macro to repeat a single character a given number of times. I want to modify the macro so that it repeats the character until the end of the line (the page width might be modified using the `geometry` package and the macro should still fill the line with the given character).

I know that `\textwidth` holds the value of the width of the current page, but I don't know how to write a loop that compares the current width against `\textwidth` in which case it would stop repeating the character.

Comment: Use leaders not counts of characters.

Comment: See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/want-to-fill-line-with-repeating-string?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.