# Resume list in the middle of an item

Tags: lists, enumitem

Is there a way to resume a list in the middle of an item using the enumitem package as in this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
%% From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16192/4011

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[a),series=foo]
\item Item 1
\item \Repeat{30}{Some Text. }
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\raisebox{-\height}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.15\linewidth);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

  %\vspace*{1ex}

  \begin{enumerate}[a),resume*=foo]
\Repeat{30}{Rest of Item 2. }
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\item` in front of `\Repeat{30}{Rest of ...}`!

Comment: @TeXnician That starts a new item. I don't want to break *after* item 2 but in the *middle* of item 2.

Comment: You could use that approach and prepend a subtraction to the counter (so that the item would start right), but you're right, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The point is that no "b)" should be printed at all, it should just resume the text.

Comment: Ok, using \item[] solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `\item[]`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
%% From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16192/4011

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[a),series=foo]
\item Item 1
\item \Repeat{30}{Some Text. }
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\raisebox{-\height}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.15\linewidth);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

  %\vspace*{1ex}

  \begin{enumerate}[a),resume*=foo]
    \item[]
\Repeat{30}{Rest of Item 2. }
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```