# How to make many columns blank in table easily?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\begin{tabular{@{}ll|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|@{}}
A & B &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\%15 blank &
\end{tabular}
```

I want to do like the above where only first two column has value and others are blank.

For each row putting many `&` can possible to create the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replicate the `&` using details from [Repeat command n times?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16189/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l l *{15}{|r} | @{} }
  A & B \Repeat{15}{& c} \\
  \Repeat{13}{&} & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A similar `\Repeat` macro is possible using [`multido`](//ctan.org/pkg/multido):

```
\usepackage{multido}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Repeat}[2]{%
  \def\@@x{}% Make sure \@@x is defined
  \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{\protected@xdef\@@x{\@@x #2}}% Create global repetition
  \@@x% Execute repetition
}
\makeatother
```

Using `\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{\multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{#2}}` won't work here because each cell within the `tabular` creates a group and the default definition of `\multido` doesn't make a global assignment of the stepping macro (`\i`). Instead, one has to assemble the repetition into a macro before executing it.

Also note the condensed way in which the column specification can be specified: `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` repeats `<col spec>` a total of `<num>` times.

Comment: Isn't it possible to specify the `\Repeat` at tabular argument `begin{tabular}{--here--}` so that I insert 1st and 2nd column in each row. `A & B\\ C & D\\ E & F\\`

Comment: I am familiar to `\multido` command. Isn't it possible with `\multido` ?

Comment: @alhelal: Yes, but it's more complicated. See the updated answer. I don't understand what you mean by your first comment.

Comment: In first comment I said that I don't want to write `\Repeat` each time for a new row.

Comment: @alhelal: `tabular`s are set by column (first) by row (second). It's therefore easier to manage a by-column replication than by-row.