# Who ate my space? (How to stop \exp_args:Nf from consuming a space?)

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3

I have a macro that uses `\prg_replicate:nn` to produce a number of spaces, then pass those spaces, after f-expanding `\prg_replicate:nn`, to another macro. The problem is that when I use `\exp_args:Nf`, it will use the `\romannumeral 0` thingy which can consume a space. Guess what, this space is removed from my replicated spaces, so after the whole thing is completed I have one space less.

The issue is reproduced with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_pre_output:n #1 { [ \tl_to_str:n {#1} ] }
\cs_set:Npn \__printf_tmp:w #1
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__printf_format_final_print:n ##1
      {
        \exp_args:Nf \__printf_pre_output:n
          { \prg_replicate:nn {##1} {#1} }
      }
  }
\__printf_tmp:w { ~ }
\ttfamily
Wrong,~4~spaces:~\__printf_format_final_print:n {5}\par
Right,~5~spaces:~[\ \ \ \ \ ]\par
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to stop `\romannumeral` from eating one of my spaces besides the obvious "do the whole thing with an extra space to begin with".

For the time being I'm doing the replication with an extra space to feed to `\romannumeral`, but it seems a hackish way to do that. Is there another possibility?

Comment: Is 'use another expansion method' a valid answer? With `\expanded` coming (already in MiKTeX), I'd just use `e`-type in new code.

Comment: @JosephWright Ooh, there's that. If it isn't possible with `f`-type, then I'd be happy with `e` :)

Comment: how many steps requires `\prg_replicate:nn` to fully expand ? if only two then you only need to expand twice.

Comment: @jfbu two steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply use the new `e`-type approach here (*i.e.* using the `\expanded` primitive or equivalent):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_pre_output:n #1 { [ \tl_to_str:n {#1} ] }
\cs_set:Npn \__printf_tmp:w #1
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__printf_format_final_print:n ##1
      {
        \exp_args:Ne \__printf_pre_output:n
          { \prg_replicate:nn {##1} {#1} }
      }
  }
\__printf_tmp:w { ~ }
\ttfamily
Wrong,~4~spaces:~\__printf_format_final_print:n {5}\par
Right,~5~spaces:~[\ \ \ \ \ ]\par
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

---

This will likely become the standard approach for such cases: `f`-type expansion is much less important now that we have `e`-type either directly using the `\expanded` primitive or (where necessary) emulated. Note that MiKTeX already has `\expanded` in pdfTeX and XeTeX, and that this will appear in TeX Live 2019. Also note that LuaTeX has had `\expanded` from day one. (Emulation is reliable but does have a performance impact: at present, it probably is best avoided for any code which needs to work in tight loops or similar.)

Answer (score 4):

Like @jfbu mentioned, expanding twice is enough for `\prg_replicate:nn`. So using `\exp_args:No` twice on it suffices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_pre_output:n #1 { [ \tl_to_str:n {#1} ] }
\cs_set:Npn \__printf_tmp:w #1
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__printf_format_final_print:n ##1
      {
        \exp_args:NNo \exp_args:No \__printf_pre_output:n
          { \prg_replicate:nn {##1} {#1} }
      }
  }
\__printf_tmp:w { ~ }
\ttfamily
Wrong,~4~spaces:~\__printf_format_final_print:n {5}\par
Right,~5~spaces:~[\ \ \ \ \ ]\par
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh, I got so deep in counting spaces that I forgot counting expansions :)

Answer (score 4):

I can only second @JosephWright and @Skillmon answers but speaking of what I know, with `xint` you only need to expand once `\romannumeral\xintreplicate{100}{ }` to get 100 spaces. So if inside a macro

```
\def\x{\romannumeral\xintreplicate{100}{ }}
```

you only need to expand `\x` twice.

Or

```
\def\x{\xintreplicate{100}{ }}
```

then you can do `\romannumeral\x`.

Oh wait, I completely forgot: `\romannumeral\xintreplicate` basically IS (up to different user interface) `\prg_replicate:nn`, I COPIED its underlying implementation `;-)`.

Comment: You naughty boy ;) But they are not _exactly_ the same. If I use `\expandafter\__printf_pre_output:n\expandafter{\romannumeral\xintreplicate{##1}{#1}}` it works correctly, but if I use `\expandafter\__printf_pre_output:n\expandafter{\romannumeral\prg_replicate:nn{##1}{#1}}` I get a `Missing number` error... Either way, I'm sticking to `expl3` in this code, so I'll leave `xint` for another time :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes only the underlying implementation is the same, not the user interface with `\romannumeral`. I will fix my confusing wording. (of course `xint` never had ambition to provide programming environment like expl3 does; if I had known about expl3 when I started coding  xint in 2013 I might have used it... but obviously I was not good at that time finding TeX documentation...)

Comment: not exactly the same (from the docs: *Using it with a negative x raises no error and does nothing.* and from code comment in sourcexint.pdf *The code in Joseph's post does `abs(#1)` replications when input `#1` is negative and then activates an error triggering macro;* This refers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/repeat-command-n-times and I don't know if posted code there is still faithfully the one from expl3)

Comment: You probably need `\romannumeral-\`0` instead of just `\romannumeral`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I wrote `\xintreplicate` to be used with `\romannumeral\xintreplicate` syntax.

Comment: (or rather to *require* `\romannumeral\xintreplicate` syntax)