# Lua loop in edef gives error, but not in newcommand! How to fully expand macros with lua loops?

Tags: macros, luatex, expansion, loops, blindtext

How can I have an `\edef`'ed (expanded) macro that has a lua loop with `tex.sprint` in it? I get an error when `tex.sprint` has another macro like `\blindtext[<n>]` in it. I do not get error if I print some non-macro strings like `Hello world!` using `tex.sprint` in the lua loop. The error also does not happen in case I do not expand (do not use `\edef`) the macro definition, and use `\newcommand` instead. Why is that so?

Below is the code that first uses `\newcommand`, and then `\edef`. First run the code as it is, in the second run uncomment the `\edef` version to see the error:

```
! Use of \\blindtext doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...

l.26    \directlua{dofile("blindtextloop.lua")}
                                           %
?
```

```
% lualatex edefloop.tex
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

% Note: This will write file blindtextloop.lua in you current directory
\begin{filecontents*}{blindtextloop.lua}
    for i=0,3 do
        tex.sprint(" \\blindtext[1] \\par")
    end
\end{filecontents*}

% Unexpanded blindtext
\newcommand{\myblindtext}{%
    \directlua{dofile("blindtextloop.lua")}%
}%

Expanding next:

\myblindtext

%% Uncomment following lines in second run to see the error:
% %Expanded blindtext
% \edef\myblindtextexpanded{%
%   \directlua{dofile("blindtextloop.lua")}%
% }%

% Already expanded:

% \myblindtextexpanded


\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of compiled output]

Comment: `\blindtext` is not expandable (like everything that scans for optional arguments).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Everything at some point gets expanded, so what do you mean by "anything that scans for optional arguments is not expandable"? Why does TeX put this restriction?

Comment: Some primitives are not expandable and `\futurelet`, which is used to implement any type of optional argument scanning is one of them.

Comment: the question isn't really related to Lua, `\edef\foo{\blindtext}` generates the error you show, and doing that in a lua (or tex) loop doesn't stop that.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/66168#66168

Comment: @HenriMenke If the only thing making macro `\blindtext` unexpandable is the presence of optional arguments, can such problem be cleanly solved by taking care of optional arguments in lua? (while tex thinks there are no optional arguments?) Just curious...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the pointer. The question is related to lua in the sense that I intended to get a solution for the problem (non expandability) while executing in a lua loop. As you correctly point out, the root of the problem is not lua; I don't think I said that either.

Comment: @reportaman Just return it inside `\unexpanded`, i.e. `tex.sprint("\\unexpanded{\\blindtext[1]}\\par")`, but it's really an XY-problem.

Comment: you may be able to do something specifically for blindtext but that is presumably not your real use case.Most latex constructs will fail in an edef. Accented (or any non ascii) letters for example. Unless you are going to re-implement all of latex in lua, not using edef is the most likely solution. As Henri says you could use `\unexpanded` but using `\unexpanded` in `\edef` is more or less the same as just using `\def`.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand a Lua loop in edef, just not `\blindtext` in this case though you don't need to expand the macro, as shown in the terminal output this results in defining
`\myblindtextexpanded`  as

```
macro:-> \blindtext [1] \par \blindtext [1] \par \blindtext [1] \par \blindtext
 [1] \par
```

so the loop has been unrolled to repeated calls of `\blindtext`.

```
% lualatex edefloop.tex
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

% Note: This will write file blindtextloop.lua in you current directory
\begin{filecontents*}{blindtextloop.lua}
    for i=0,3 do
        tex.sprint(" \\noexpand\\blindtext[1] \\par")
    end
\end{filecontents*}

% Unexpanded blindtext
\newcommand{\myblindtext}{%
    \directlua{dofile("blindtextloop.lua")}%
}%

Expanding next:

\myblindtext

%% Uncomment following lines in second run to see the error:
 %Expanded blindtext
 \edef\myblindtextexpanded{%
   \directlua{dofile("blindtextloop.lua")}%
 }%

% Already expanded:

\typeout{\meaning\myblindtextexpanded}

\myblindtextexpanded


\end{document}
```