# Check if key is set in xkeyval

Tags: key-value, xkeyval

I am working with the `xkeyval` package.

Sometimes I want to check by hand if a key is contained in a list of keys.

That is, I want a if-command like the following:

```
\contains@key{<family>}{<key value pairs>}{<key>}
{<execute if <key> is contained in <key value pairs>>}
{<execute if key is not contained>}
```

Are there already commands in xkeyval to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The following defines a fully expandable macro that checks whether the key is in the list. It uses `expkv` to loop over the list of key=value pairs and `pdftexcmds` to make `\pdf@strcmp` available in all engines. The key names are not expanded in any way in this process. The macro needs exactly two steps of expansion to do its job.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifkeyinlistTF[1]
  {\romannumeral\expandafter\ifkeyinlistTF@\detokenize{#1}\relax}
\long\def\ifkeyinlistTF@#1\relax#2%
  {%
    \ekvparse{\ifkeyinlistTF@k{#1}}{\ifkeyinlistTF@v{#1}}{#2}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF@false
  }
\newcommand\ifkeyinlistTF@k[2]
  {\if0\pdf@strcmp{#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}\ifkeyinlistTF@true\fi}
\newcommand\ifkeyinlistTF@v[3]
  {\if0\pdf@strcmp{#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}\ifkeyinlistTF@true\fi}
\newcommand\ifkeyinlistTF@false[2]{\z@#2}
\long\def\ifkeyinlistTF@true\fi#1\ifkeyinlistTF@false#2#3{\fi\z@#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\edef\foo
  {%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i}{.}{a}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i,key}{i}{.}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i,keya}{.}{q}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i,key=a}{u}{.}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i,key=}{i}{.}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i, key=}{t}{.}%
    \ifkeyinlistTF{\key}{a,b=c,d,e=f,g,h=i, \key =}{a}{.}%
  }
\texttt{\meaning\foo}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is meant by a fully expandable macro and what is the advantage of having such one?

Comment: @aiquita see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros for some explanations.

Comment: @aiquita also, my code is 7 times faster on the key=value lists used in my answer (with the last one changed from using `\key` to `key`). And my code is alignment safe, whereas the `xkeyval` internals are not (oh oh, next complicated TeX-term; explanation: Your code can't be used inside `tabular` and friends if either the key or one of the values contains `&` outside of an additional set of braces).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out myself how to achieve a command that takes a key, a list of key-value pairs, and executes some of two code blocks depending on whether the key occurs in the list.

The solution is build upon low level commands of the `xkeyval` package, thus well-suited if you already use the package. At least I use the command along with setting the keys in `xkeyval`.

For comparision I use the `ifthen` package which may be replaced by any other sufficient mechanism.

The solution is as follows:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \makeatletter
        
        \newcommand{\if@contains@key}[4]{%
            \XKV@checksanitizea{#2}\XKV@resb%
            \newif\ifkey@found\key@foundfalse% set to true right after the key was found, otherwise remains false
            \XKV@for@o\XKV@resb\XKV@tempa{% loop over the key-value pairs
                % the following two lines extract the key from the pair and remove trailing whitespace (same solution as in \setkeys of xkeyval)
                \expandafter\XKV@g@tkeyname\XKV@tempa=\@nil\XKV@tempa%
                \expandafter\KV@@sp@def\expandafter\XKV@tempa\expandafter{\XKV@tempa}%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\XKV@tempa}}%
                    {\key@foundtrue}{}%
            }%
            \ifkey@found%
                #3%
            \else%
                #4%
            \fi%
        }
        
    
        \if@contains@key{welt}{hallo={}, welt={}}
            {Hallo}
            {Welt}
        
    \makeatother

\end{document}
```

Note that the solution works on the list of key-value pairs directly such that it does not check whether the key belongs to a certain family of keys.

Comment: In your code, move `\newif\ifkey@found` outside of the code of `\if@contains@key` (but keep the `\key@foundfalse`). You don't need to redefine the conditional on each call of your macro.