# Reasons for not using \protect

Tags: protected-macro, fragile

So I have been looking into the details of what it means for a macro to be `\protect`ed and thus be made robust. I have found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/128658) where an answer explains the concept of what it means for a command to be fragile and what `\protect` does to fix this, quite well.

However, now I have to wonder: Is there any reason why I would want my command to NOT be robust (aka not use`\protect` in its definition)? After all, fragile commands seem to cause all kinds of problems and the fix appears to (almost) always be to just add a `\protect` to the command (or use e.g. `\NewDocumentCommand` from the `xparse` package, which afaik does automatically create a protected, aka robust command).

Comment: When you want your command to be fully expandable?  [tex core - Advantages and disadvantages of fully expandable macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/)

Comment: Side note -- nowadays creating robust command uses `\protected`, not `\protect`, which is better in a few ways.

Comment: @user202729 No, LaTeX2e `\DeclareRobustCommand` is unchanged, it still uses `\protect`.

Comment: Note `\NewDocumentCommand ` does not use the LaTeX `\protect` mechanism, but the e-tex `\protected` primitive, which has overlapping use cases with `\protect` but is fundamentally different

Comment: Well, then, most of the time it's recommended to create robust commands instead of patching them with \protect (which clutters the source code up), and if you create robust command it's better to use the \protected mechanism than to use the old \protect (which is I think a bit faster and works with raw TeX primitive etc.)

Comment: @user202729 except the cases where `\protect` works but `\protected` commands do not (notably if the input ends up being used in a `\csname`, `\protect` (should be) locally `\string` so will work, but `\protected` tokens do not expand so generate low level csname error.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Valid point. But in practice you hardly actually want to construct such a csname anyway...? (or if you insist, maybe for "hashing a token list" (roughly), just detokenize the whole thing?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\abc{center}

\newcommand\redef[2]{\def#1{#2}}

\begin{document}


\typeout{here: \abc}

\begin{\abc}
  xxx
\end{\abc}

\redef{\abc}{xyz}

\typeout{here: \abc}

\end{document}
```

Which produces a log of

```
here: center
here: xyz
```

If you add `\protect` before `\abc` in the `\typeout` the log is

```
here: \abc
here: \abc
```

If you add `\protect`  in the argument to `\redef` the log is

```
! Use of \protect doesn't match its definition.
\end ...after \z@ \expandafter \protect \fi \end  
                                                  
l.20 \end
         {document}
?
```

As  `\protect` has been redefined, not `\abc`

So it depends on the context. `\protect` prevents expansion, but the current context may be expecting expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\abc{center}

\newcommand\redef[2]{\def#1{#2}}

\begin{document}


\typeout{here: \protect\abc}

\begin{\abc}
  xxx
\end{\abc}

\redef{\protect\abc}{xyz}

\typeout{here: \protect\abc}

\end{document}
```