I want to compare the last character of a string with other characters
I want to compare the last character of a string with other characters.
If I type
\ifthenelse{\equal{f}{f}}{OK}{NOT OK}

it returns OK. HOWEVER, if I type
\substr{asdf}{-1}{1}

it returns f, BUT
\ifthenelse{\equal{\substr{asdf}{-1}{1}}{f}}{OK}{NOT OK}

says Argument of \equal has an extra }.
Probably the answer is trivial, but I have spent several hours, read dozens of posts, and nothing works.
Thank you very much in advance!


You did not mention it but you appear to be using xstring and ifthen packages. xstring functions are almost always non-expandable and so can not be used in conditionals.
LaTeX provides expandable functions to take characters from a string and do comparisons without needing any package:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\IfLastEqualTF{mm}{
  \str_if_eq:eeTF {\str_item:nn{#1}{-1}}  {\str_item:nn{#2}{-1}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

last of asdf = f? \IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{f}{yes}{no}

last of asdf = g? \IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{g}{yes}{no}

last of áéíóú = ú  \IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ú}{yes}{no}

last of áéíóú = ó \IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ó}{yes}{no}

\end{document}


Note this actually just compares the last byte of the utf-8 encoding of each argument. So for non ascii characters it is not actually an equality test but so long as you only need characters in the range of accented European latin script it's safe enough.
To do an actual equality test on the last character would require using commands that are aware of the utf-8 encoding from the \text_... module, I may add something later

Wow, you impressed me, thank you! If you don't mind, I have another couple of (probably very silly) questions. The function does not work, e.g., when I used special accented letters, like áéíóú. Is there a way to consider non-ASCII characters? And another (probably very ignorant) question: what is the difference between an expandable and a non-expandable function? Is it possible to turn a non-expandable function into an expandable one? Thank you very much again.

@User I updated for accented characters, on expandability you can search this site or start from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/66168#66168

I can't see a fast way of getting the end of an arbitrary UTF-8 text in an 8-bit engine: will need to use \text_map_function:nN and collect up the last entry - all doable but not that efficient.

@JosephWright yes that was best I could think of too. or regexp match for a utf8 sequence at the end but that's probably even worse for efficiency

@JosephWright or iterate backwards doing \str_item:nn{#2}{-n} until you get a byte with the second bit set then reconstitute the utf-8 sequence collected. I'm not sure how inefficient the -n indexing is

@DavidCarlisle That only gets one codepoint: if you have a multi-codepoint grapheme ...

@JosephWright sure but I think codepoints are often enough, and in pdftex, probably already more than enough:-)

@User I see egreg has added a version with \text functions. as I comment in the answer that's more complete, but more complicated:-) But means I won't add another version here

You can do this expandably, but certainly not with xstring.
The idea is to split the given text into items, bracing them and checking the last item.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfLastEqualTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF
   { \tl_item:en { \text_map_function:nN { #1 } \__user_brace_items:n } { -1 } } % last item
   { #2 } % item to check against
   { #3 } % true text
   { #4 } % false text
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { e }
\cs_new:Nn \__user_brace_items:n { {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

last of asdf = f? \IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{f}{yes}{no}

last of asdf = g? \IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{g}{yes}{no}

last of áéíóú = ú  \IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ú}{yes}{no}

last of áéíóú = ó \IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ó}{yes}{no}

\IfLastEqualTF{三人}{人}{yes}{no}

\IfLastEqualTF{三人}{三}{yes}{no}

\end{document}


You might branch for Unicode and non Unicode engines, because in the former case the test can be made much more efficient.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfLastEqualTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \__user_lastitem:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

 
\sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \__user_lastitem:n
   {
    \tl_item:en { \text_map_function:nN { #1 } \__user_brace_items:n } { -1 }
   }
 }
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \__user_lastitem:n { \str_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { e }
\cs_new:Nn \__user_brace_items:n { {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

last of asdf = f? \IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{f}{yes}{no}

last of asdf = g? \IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{g}{yes}{no}

last of áéíóú = ú  \IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ú}{yes}{no}

last of áéíóú = ó \IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ó}{yes}{no}

\IfLastEqualTF{三人}{人}{yes}{no}

\IfLastEqualTF{三人}{三}{yes}{no}

\end{document}


Thank you. Really impressive. One thing, the code runs beautifully, but, if I write the data in a .csv file and import them by means of \csvreader, it fails. What can be the reason?

@User Please, open a new question with the details.

Done! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720728/problems-when-extracting-chars-from-data-imported-from-csv-file Thank you guys for all your feedback!
