Problems when extracting chars from data imported from csv file
In a previous post
I want to compare the last character of a string with other characters
I asked how to compare the last character of a string with another char, and the solutions offered have solved my problem. However, I have observed that, if I import the strings from a .csv file, they fail. I offer here a minimal example:
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    asdf
    qwer
    uioe
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\IfLastEqualTF{mm}{
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {\str_item:nn{#1}{-1}}  {\str_item:nn{#2}{-1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{qwer}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{uioe}{f}{yes}{no}

\csvreader[no head]{test.csv}{}
\csvreader[no head]{test.csv}{}
{
    \csvcoli~\IfLastEqualTF{\csvcoli}{f}{yes}{no}
}

\end{document}

When I execute it, I get

yes no no
asdf no  qwer no  uioe no

but I should get

yes no no
asdf yes  qwer no  uioe no

Why does this happen? Because \csvreader reads correctly the file, but then the strings do not have the same behavior as when I type them inside the .tex file.

You need one more expansion step, namely to fully expand \csvcoli before the action of \str_if_eq:nnTF.
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
    asdf
    qwer
    uioe
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\IfLastEqualTF{mm}
  {
    \user_iflastequal:en { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \user_iflastequal:nn
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {\str_item:nn{#1}{-1}}  {\str_item:nn{#2}{-1}}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_iflastequal:nn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{qwer}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{uioe}{f}{yes}{no}

\csvreader[no head]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
    \csvcoli~\IfLastEqualTF{\csvcoli}{f}{yes}{no}
}

\end{document}


If you need accented characters, full expansion is dangerous. For this case I suggest to use a *-variant when the argument has to be extracted from a control sequence such as \csvcoli.
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
    asdf
    qwer
    uioe
    áéíóú
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfLastEqualTF}{smmmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \user_iflastequal:Vnnn #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
   {
    \user_iflastequal:nnnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \user_iflastequal:nnnn
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \__user_lastitem:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_iflastequal:nnnn { V }
 
\sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \__user_lastitem:n
   {
    \tl_item:en { \text_map_function:nN { #1 } \__user_brace_items:n } { -1 }
   }
 }
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \__user_lastitem:n { \str_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { e }
\cs_new:Nn \__user_brace_items:n { {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfLastEqualTF{asdf}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{qwer}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{uioe}{f}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ú}{yes}{no}
\IfLastEqualTF{áéíóú}{ó}{yes}{no}

\csvreader[no head]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
    \csvcoli~\IfLastEqualTF*{\csvcoli}{f}{yes}{no}
}

\csvreader[no head]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
    \csvcoli~\IfLastEqualTF*{\csvcoli}{ú}{yes}{no}
}

\end{document}



Thank you very very much! BTW, what does "to fully expand" mean? Is there any reference on this? Thank you again!
