# Why is there no pgfmath macro that expands directly to the result?

Tags: pgfmath

Is there a specific reason that there is no default macro (e.g. `\pgfmath{<expression>}`) that directly expands to the result of the evaluated `<expression>`? It always strikes me as particularly cumbersome when I have to type `\pgfmathparse{\linewidth-2.7cm}\pgfmathresult` just to calculate some length that's only used once.

Since such macros would come quite handy for single-use calculations I tried to define my own, but to no avail. Can you help me out with these definitions or at least expain why such a thing is not possible?

What bothers me is the fact that both my `\pgflength` and the default `\pgfmathresult` are just macros (according to `\show`) and both ultimately expand to a sequence of numbers. `:-(`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\pgfmath[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand\pgftrunc[1]{\pgfmathparse{int(#1)}\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand\pgflength[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult pt}

\begin{document}
% Fails:
%\hspace{\pgflength{1cm+2cm}}

% Error message:
% ! Missing number, treated as zero.
% <to be read again> 
%                  \begingroup 
% l.14     \hspace{\pgflength{1cm+2cm}}

% Works:
\pgfmathparse{1cm+2cm}
\hspace{\pgfmathresult pt}

% Curiously this also fails:
%\edef\mylength{\pgflength{1cm+2cm}}

% Error message:
% ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 24.
% <inserted text> 
%                 \fi 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\pgfmath` is not expandable, and so has to be used with a 'known' output macro to provide the result (for more on expandable code, see for example [Tricks to make macros expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/tricks-to-make-macros-expandable) and [Why isn't everything expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable)). The [LaTeX3 FPU](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3kernel/l3fp.dtx) is expandable, and so you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\fpmath}[1]{\fp_eval:n{#1}}
\newcommand{\fptrunc}[1]{\fp_to_int:n{#1}}
\newcommand{\fplength}[1]{\fp_eval:n{#1}~pt~}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\hspace{\fplength{1cm+2cm}}

\edef\mylength{\fplength{1cm+2cm}}

\end{document}
```

The LaTeX3 FPU currently does not have the same coverage as the `pgfmath` code, and some things will never be possible in an expandable way (for example measuring material typeset into boxes). The expandable FPU is also slower than non-expandable code in many cases (here roughly twice as long is needed for the calculation, although the precision is higher).