# (Why) Can't we get 'fully expandable' versions of every command?

Tags: boxes, expansion

I'm just starting to figure out what 'expandable' means in LaTeX, and why it is useful to have commands that expand as far as possible. In particular:

- If you want to `\typeout` some string to the log file, you need to be able to expand all the way to it.
- If you want to do any kind of unit-testing (like with [`qstest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/qstest)), you need to be able to expand at least down to the strings you want to compare.

I've been reading a lot about this topic. As I understand it, a command is not expandable if it changes the 'state' in some way, i.e., uses `\def`, `\let`, etc. In particular, I've also read the question ["Why isn't everything expandable"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable). But my question is less theoretical than that one. I'd like to know why I haven't encountered any 'solutions' yet.

The thing is, 'making everything expandable' is conceptually so simple. TeX is perfectly capable of *typesetting* the result of 'unexpandable' commands, simply by performing the state changes in the execution processor. The point being, TeX does eventually arrive at the final string.

*(Edit: Please note that I'm talking about textual characters here. I understand that one cannot capture the notion of, e.g., an image, flexible whitespace or a state-manipulation in a string.)*

It seems inconceivable to me that we can't somehow intercept it and use it. I would have expected someone to have created a command like this:

```
\getresult { <expr> } { <result-macro> }
```

It's not expandable, but we can still get our hands on the fully expanded result in order to log it... compare it... what have you.

Questions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/are-there-purely-expandable-variants-of-makeuppercase) suggest to me that this has not been accomplished.

**Why?**

Ok... I'm willing to cheat. What if we spawn an extra TeX process to fully evaluate the expression and (almost) typeset it. Can we get the string that way? Doesn't `\scantokens` use a similar trick to overcome another inherent TeX limitation (that catcodes are fixed once a token is read)?

**Can it be done?**

Comment: I suspect you are mixing up what you see on a typeset page (probably mainly letters) with what TeX 'sees' (boxes, kerns, glue, font selection, ...). For example, what doe would the full expansion of something like `\hbox{ABC\hskip 1 cm DEF}` be? For example, take a look at the `\tracingall` output of a typeset page.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was talking about capturing characters. I will edit my question to clarify this point. ### I do know that when I generate a document with TeX, the resulting text is not lost. It doesn't become a 'bitmap'. I know, because I can still select and copy the text from my document viewer.

Comment: TeX doesn't really have a concept of "textual characters". You're talking about box contents here. In fact, with modern Unicode-aware systems it might even make some sense to try to recover the "text content" of a box, but TeX doesn't offer that out-of-the-box. Maybe it could be programmed in LuaTeX?

Comment: Would you please add an example of what you *really* need?

Comment: As you purposefully edited out the [tag:luatex] tag, the answer is clearly *no, it can't be done*.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I'm sorry for removing your tag. No offense intended. I just thought it was out of place, since my question wasn't about LuaTex.

Comment: @mhelvens Well but this way nobody who could answer your question in the affirmative will read it.

Comment: Just to add some info: category codes are irrelevant for this kind of problems.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I'm aware of that. I just used `\scantokens` as an example of a command that sort of goes around the TeX core to do something that would otherwise not be possible. ### @StephanLehmke I understand. And an answer in the negative is quite acceptable, if I can understand why. But I was talking about 'plain' (La)TeX. (I can understand that access to a general purpose programming language such as Lua could solve many such problems. But not everyone uses LuaTex.)

Comment: @egreg I wanted to keep this question more general, partly out of intellectual curiosity. Since it now seems that the answer is *no*, I will follow up with questions about my specific problems.

Comment: FWIW, the recent trend in ConTeXt is to make all macros **unexpandable** by default, and move operations that were done based on expandable macros into lua.

Comment: With the new LuaTeX `runtoks` actually allows some previously unexpandable things expandable (e.g. [compare two token lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227592/define-an-expandable-function-for-comparing-a-token-list-to-a-string-in-latex3), changing macro definition, etc.), or [`immediateassignment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570700/why-doesn-t-tex-allow-local-expandable-definitions-inside-commands).

Comment: See also: [tex core - Tricks to make macros expandable - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/tricks-to-make-macros-expandable)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that this assumption is basically false:

> The point being, TeX does eventually arrive at the final string

It is not like C and its macro pre-processor cpp where all the expansion happens first resulting in an expanded version of the C file which can be passed to the C compiler (or intercepted for debugging or other reasons). In TeX non expandable operations and expansion are inextricably interwoven.

The classic example is

```
    \setbox0\hbox{hello}\the\wd0
```

`\wd0` is expandable and expands to the decimal expression of the width of box 0. However you can not expand it until you have dome the non-expandable operation of typesetting text into the box.

so given

```
 \def\foo#1{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\the\wd0}
```

You can not have an expandable version of the command `\foo`.

---

The distinction between expandable and non expandable is often arbitrary. So the answer is that in TeX it can not be done. It's like saying my name is David. There are alternative  histories where different things may have been true but we have the system we have.

Consider arithmetic:in classic TeX to print one more than some value you have to go

```
\advance\mycount by 1 \the\mycount
```

and that is a non-expandable operation. In etex you can go

```
\the\numexpr\mycount+1\relax
```

which is an expandable operation. There is no *reason* that one can argue for why one version of arithemtic is expandable and the other is not. It just is. If someone is extending TeX (eTeX, pdftex xetex, tex part of luatex ) then any new primitive that is added has to be classified as expandable or not expandable as the TeX programming language requires that distinction. Commands are expandable or non expandable because the person who designed them classified them that way.

As noted in the comments, a possible workaround of writing out fragments to a sub-process running a different instance of TeX can not help, even if `\write` were expandable. The result of evaluating any argument is highly context dependent (it may involve references, definitions within the document or reference the time the job started) it would be impossible in general to generate the same text in the sub process as generated in the original process.

---

It's probably worth noting that the term in quotes in the question "fully expandable" isn't well defined (or definable) which is part of the reason for the confusion around the topic of expansion. As discussed in an earlier question
[Advantages and disadvantages of fully expandable macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/66168#66168)
a better term is "safe in an expansion only context". Commands that are safe in such expansion only contexts as `\edef` or `\write` include character tokens and the `\relax` primitive mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I understand your point. However, it does not negate the fact that a solution should be possible. ### An 'expandable version of `\foo`' is ambiguous here, I suppose. Do you still want the box to be typeset, or only to serve as a basis for calculating the width? ### In the second case, I could serve the definition of foo (unexpanded) to a new TeX process, let it typeset the box, and retrieve only the width value. The first case may be even simpler. I'm not sure.

Comment: @mhelvens A second TeX process will not solve the expandability problem, at least without LuaTeX, as `\write18` is not expandable.

Comment: @JosephWright Ah, I see. That's a good reason. And would `\write18` be the only way to do something like that? What does `\scantokens` do? Is `\scantokens` a part of the TeX engine, rather than a user-defined command? Perhaps an extension to TeX could be proposed that solves 'my' problem.

Comment: @mhelvens All write operations are non-expandable as they depend on the OS. The `\scantokens` primitive is part of e-TeX, and operates in a way analogous to a file operation but _without_ any real file I/O. That can only be achieved at an engine level, so for pdfTeX/XeTeX there is no way to 'escape' from what is expandable.

Comment: @JosephWright I understand. Thanks for the information. However, I suppose it's not a 'fundamental' reason, but rather a design decision (or oversight?) for TeX. I believe that a useful command akin to `\scantokens` *could* be added to the (e-)TeX engine that would solve many expansion problems TeX-programmers are having.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle While your answer is quite informative, I don't think it fully answers my question. I believe Josephs comment (that `\write18` and any other OS dependent commands are not expandable either, so there's no way 'around' it) completes your answer. I accept your answer, but perhaps you could still add something to that effect, for completeness sake.

Comment: @mhelvens I added some extra notes to the answer but you passing to a second TeX process is not workable, I used `hello` in the example but really the argument of `\foo` can include arbitrary Tex information including the current state of all macros, the current jobame, the time the job started. consider `\foo{\the\time}` or even `\foo{\cite{bar}}` It would be very hard to get these strings just by typesetting this fragment.

Comment: @David On your edit about it being arbitrary, there are some cases where things being expandable might make the language more tricky to use. The example given in one of the other questions was `\endgroup`, but `\relax` might also go into this category.

Comment: The comments got added later (I think) but I think that is covered by my additional notes that some primitives are classified as non expandable \setbox \write and \advance examples are all essentially the same here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the answer can still benefit from the information that `\write` is not a backdoor to get around the problem: because it is not expandable itself. ### In any case, thanks to you both for giving me more insight!

Comment: @JosephWright yes of course. You could just declare everything is expandable but then you would have to think of a new word for the distinctions that are necessary. It depends a bit what the intention is The OP said "expansion problems TeX-programmers are having" But I don't think making things expandable actually solves any of those problems, it is perhaps more accurate to say that people have problems programming TeX.

Comment: Even if \write were expandable I doubt there are many cases where it would help for the reasons I gave. TeX is almost always highly context dependent, It is almost never possible to execute a fragment in isolation (which is why we always ask for complete documents as examples in questions, without that code fragments are often unusable)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (in response to your last two comments) That is, of course, only partly true. There are many cases where 'making non-expandable commands expandable' would be both quite safe and tremendously useful. You're of course quite right that it could be very difficult or damaging in the general case. ### The problem is finding a suitable dividing line. And I think TeX may currently be drawing it too much to the safe side. ### In any case, again, your answers and comments have, as always, been enormously useful. Thanks! (Also to Stephan. I should definitely look at LuaTex some day.)

Comment: The main hurdle is that a) in TeX all assignments are non-expanable and b) that to operate (in an exapandable manner) on typeset text you first have to assign it to a box. So whenever typsetting is involved you are having to jump to the non-expandable side  and there is no way to change this in the model. And that means anything that requires measuring of material, for example is doomed

Comment: You say "currently" but mostly that line was drawn by Knuth in 1979 so it's not always where you would want but it is where it is.

Comment: I still think your question isn't really about expansion (but rather about getting at box contents), but considering expandability, please note that an important property of the current concept of expandability is that (considering the state of the engine stays the same) no information is "lost" by expansion, it's mainly a transformation of content. Hence it make sense to store the expanded version of a token list in a register. As soon as you start executing things, a lot of information goes into state changes and side effects, so is "lost" from the text being processed.

Answer (score 10):

Understanding "expandable" as TeX does is tricky, because there are really two kinds of result for a TeX command sequence (something such as `\foo`, which is commonly called a "macro", but which I won't because that has the baggage of macro expansion, which I'm trying to demystify rather than further confuse).  I'll be using made-up terms for these.

- The first kind of result is *input*, and this is what happens after "expanding" `\foo`.  This just replaces `\foo` with other tokens that can be further scanned by TeX.
- The second kind of result is *output*, and this is what happens when the result is *no longer* scanned by TeX.  This has two sub-types:
  (a) *Internal output*.  This is what the programming constructs like `\def` and `\let` do, as well as other assignments like `\count0=1` that aren't exactly implemented by a control sequence.
  (b) *External output*.  This is what is *typeset*.  However, even if nothing ever made it to the page, it is still placed in a box in memory, and the contents of the box are rendered with fonts and explicit spacing.

TeX's operation is a long crawl through a stream of *input* tokens that are either converted to *external output* (if they are directly typesettable material like letters or other font symbols, or are boxes and such), to *internal output*, if they are assignments of some kind and thus "save" their result for later use, or to more *input*, if they simply expand right back into the input stream.  These processes can be mixed, of course, such as when you assign to a box register (as internal output) a box that was produced as external output.

The process of expansion is *blind*: it does not interact with the mechanisms that produce external output.  These are the measurement and placement mechanisms, so the example of `\setbox0=\hbox{hello}\the\wd0`, in passing through the external output mechanism to do the width computation, is necessarily non-expandable, because width does not exist at the input level.  (As it happens, it also has to pass through the internal output mechanism to save the box, but that is dictated only by the design of TeX that forbids you from writing `\the\wd\hbox{hello}`.)

Now, you ask for the "final result" of something that is typeset to be available as *input*.  I think what you mean is the following:

You want to circumvent the restriction on expanding *internal output*, i.e. you want `\def\foo{hello}\foo` to be converted to `hello`.  This sounds like a reasonable request that, as David Carlisle said, is simply impossible.  TeX designates `\def` to be non-expandable and that's it.  One wonders (I once did) why `\def` does not "expand" to nothing as well as making the definition, and there's no reason I know of, but the fact is that as things stand, it passes through the *internal output* mechanism and therefore does not directly manipulate the input stream.

If I may philosophize some more, what you are requesting is I think a common way of "doing it wrong".  You want to issue a programming construct that results in further *input* that is also valid as a programming construct for producing *external output*.  Since the two languages, though intertwined, are actually different, this is impossible.  That doesn't mean there aren't equivalent ways of writing your *input* construct so that it creates what you want.  A common workaround is to do a lot of non-expandable stuff that repeatedly builds a macro `\result`, and then its contents are available expandably afterwards (this is what the previous examples do, actually).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe David's answer can be complemented by a non-TeX perspective.

As TeX macro processing is comparable to a programming language the notion of expandable versus non-expandable does exist in computer science but with different wording.

Essentially a fully expandable macro or function is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), i.e. a function without side effects that does not depend on anything but it's arguments. In pseudo-C:

```
int twice(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}
```

For a given string it does not change the output whether we replace the function by it's return values: twice(4) is equal to 8. Now we take a slightly modified function and end up with something that is inherently non-expandable:

```
int twice_current_page()
{
    return 2*current_page;
}
```

twice_current_page() cannot be replaced/expanded in the document. The only way to get the result is to execute everything up to this point and then execute the function body.

Comment: This is very far from the usual understanding of *expandable* wrt. TeX.

Comment: @StephanLemke: Yes, I tried with `C` as an example language but I am not sure if it translates nicely back to TeX, feel free to improve.

Answer (score 2):

On a second read of the question, I notice the question internally asks for something different from the title.

I discuss in [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649273/250119) on which tasks can and cannot be done expandably. (and how it's caused by the lack of primitives / `\immediateassignment` in LuaTeX can workaround these.)

---

Here I answer this particular question

> It seems inconceivable to me that we can't somehow intercept it and use it. I would have expected someone to have created a command like this:
>
> ```
> \getresult { <expr> } { <result-macro> }
> ```
>
> *It's not expandable*, but we can still get our hands on the fully expanded result in order to log it... compare it... what have you.

**It's possible**. That's precisely what the [`unravel` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61010/250119) does. <sub>(up to a few implementation simplifications. For example I believe currently it does not respect the char code of `{`/`}` tokens, tokenize the whole argument at once, and I don't think it handles expandable `\@@input`.)</sub>

(currently it "simulates" TeX expandable and unexpandable operations unexpandably; however, in principle, with a few modifications it's possible to collect the resulting "characters" that is going to be executed instead of executing them)

As the OP being already aware, you need to figure out what to do with `\hskip` / `\char` etc. yourself.

[side note, spawning an extra TeX process does not work, mostly because of the font commands/"list of currently defined macros".]

However, nobody does this in practice. Because:

**It's terribly slow.**

This doesn't need clarification. TeX isn't a very fast language to begin with.

**There's a much-faster reasonably-easy-to-use way.**

This part I explained in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649273/250119): instead of

```
\def \foo #1 {\setbox 0 \hbox {#1} \the \wd 0}
```

you do

```
\def \foo #1 {\setbox 0 \hbox {#1} \edef \result {\the \wd 0}}
```

then `\result` is expandable to your desired result.

Okay, this is only "reasonably easy to use" instead of "very easy to use", in particular you need to use temporary "variables" to pass around information instead of just nest the values.

There are efforts to ease the programmer's mental burden and avoid the need of temporary variables in this case, see the linked answer.

---

By the way, nitpick on one of the answer above.

**It's possible to increment a number by 1 expandably without `\numexpr`.**

The implementation details is left as an exercise for the reader. But it's possible.

The "measure the width of some box" remains impossible (I believe so. It isn't even possible to get the width of a single character in a font...?).

And another note.

**Unexpandable `\scantokens` can be simulated easily.**

Just write the content to an external file then read it back.

**Expandable `\scantokens` can be simulated with an `unravel`-like approach.**

Same as above. Needless to say, you need to wrap the whole code to be executed inside some outermost macro for the simulation to work.

Comment: Spurious spaces for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: There's an example implementation of "decrease 1" without e-TeX in multiexpand package.

Answer (score 1):

I think much of the confusion here results from the fact that the initial question asker probably didn't really have the technical sense of expandable used in TeX in mind when he said 'the full result of executing a given macro.'  Most answers seem to assume he meant something like the complete macro expansion in TeX but I think he had something much more akin to the effect of that macro on TeX state.  In other words the question is why can't we specify some higher level intermediate format that specifies the *complete* effect of any macro on the TeX system but is free from any macro expansion (e.g. is primitive recursive so not Turing complete)

Theoretically it is certainly possible as one can borrow the trick used in functional programming to avoid side effects and write a recursive functional TeX evaluator that uses a monad to capture both macro (re)definition and any other effects of TeX primitives.  Thus, one could identify the 'full evaluation' of a sequence of tokens (provided they are properly brace balanced and don't, on expansion, end with a ifx/expandafter/etc.. or follow an expandafter) with the sequence of monad transformers executed during evaluation of that sequence or results of its expansion.  And if one wants to be really picky we can require that both these monad transformers and the final conversion to pdf be primitive recursive to ensure they can't hide macro expansion in them.

Now that we have a proof of existence, more practically, one could attempt to simply sit down and decompose all the operations of the TeX interpreter into a small set of instructions the modify the program state during executions and simply save the list of what instructions were executed during evaluation of a certain sequence of tokens to get the desired notion.