# Section and subsection colors using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, color, titlesec

Im trying to alter the colors on my section, subsection and subsubsection.

I do so using the titlesec page:

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{red}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{red}}
```

But the problem is i have to enter the font and font size also. I am using the fontenc package:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But i cant seem to find out what font and size is being used for the section, subsection and subsubsection.

These 2 values i mean: `\Large\bfseries\sffamily`

I tried to look in the .sty but that wasent very helpful.

Comment: What document class do you use?

Comment: report, and Martins answer looks like rocket sience to me. Is there no easier way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument of the `\titleformat*{\<name>}{<code>}` is stored in a macro called `\ttlf@<name>` which (default) definition can be printed to the command line with `\show\ttlf@<name>`, after a `\makeatletter` of course.

```
\makeatletter
\show\ttlf@section

\ttlf@section:
macro:->\ttlh@hang {\normalfont \Large \bfseries }{\@seccntformat {section}}{\z
@ }{\ttl@passexplicit }{}. 

\show\ttlf@subsection

\ttlf@subsection:
macro:->\ttlh@hang {\normalfont \large \bfseries }{\@seccntformat {subsection}}
{\z@ }{\ttl@passexplicit }{}. 

\show\ttlf@subsubsection    

\ttlf@subsubsection:
macro:->\ttlh@hang {\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }{\@seccntformat {subsubs
ection}}{\z@ }{\ttl@passexplicit }{}.
```

Therefore the correct settings for the requested title formats are:

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{red}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{red}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{red}}
```

Just for completeness here also the settings for `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`:

```
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{red}}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{red}}
```

Comment: I got it, guess it was too early. Thx

Comment: @Toroo: I added the final result now for more clarity for you and other people which want to do the same thing.

Comment: Hi, any idea how to tweak this s.t it does not mess up numbering ? Just removing the asterix after \titleformat does not work for me. Thx !

Comment: @AnaK: What is the exact problem with the numbering in your document?

Answer (score 7):

This is more a comment on Martin's answer, but it's too long, so I'm putting it as a community wiki answer.

For more user-friendliness, you can define a `\addtotitleformat` macro which allows you to only write

```
\addtotitleformat*{\subsection}{\sffamily\color{blue}}
```

without having to repeat the other formatting information each time. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@secondofsix[6]{#2}
\newcommand{\addtotitleformat}{%
  \@ifstar{\addtotitleformat@star}{\addtotitleformat@nostar}}
\newcommand\addtotitleformat@nostar[2]{%
  \PackageError{titlesec}{non starred form of \string\addtotitleformat\space not supported}{}}
\newcommand\addtotitleformat@star[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@currentsection@font
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondofsix
       \csname ttlf@\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}%
  \titleformat*{#1}{\@currentsection@font#2}%
}
\makeatother

\addtotitleformat*{\section}{\Huge\color{red}}
\addtotitleformat*{\subsection}{\sffamily\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

\subsection{Section title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here [my `\multexpafter`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/can-one-define-a-superexpandaftern-that-would-expand-to-2n-1-expandafter/8117#8117) would be handy ...

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, it would allow just to type `\multexpafter3\def\multexpafter3\@currentsection@font\multexpafter4{\multexpafter2\@secondofsix`. Are you planning on making a package out of your code? It would then be much easier to use than to have to copy the code each time.

Comment: I've never ever been close to writing a package, so if _you_ have a package where you think it would be worth to include, please do (and just acklowledge the author in the code).

Comment: @Hendrik: As `\multexpafter` is a helper macro, a standalone package would be preferable for it. Doing a package out of your code is just a matter of copying it to a `.tex` file, making a three-line `.sty` file which inputs it and then a short pdf file explaining how to use it. If you want, I can do that for you but as author of the code, you should be the package maintainer since you're the one who knows it best.

Comment: Thanks for those explanations. Now it seems, however, that Bruno should write a package that includes [his `\MultiExpandAfter`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/can-one-define-a-superexpandaftern-that-would-expand-to-2n-1-expandafter/10877#10877).