# Macros with # as the last parameter

Tags: macros

Knuth hid a special rule for delimited arguments in exercise 20.5 of the TeXbook.

> If the very last character of the
>   parameter text is #, so that this #
>   is immediately followed by {, TeX
>   will behave as if the { had been
>   inserted at the right end of both the
>   parameter text and the replacement
>   text.

This means that a macro can be defined as,

```
\def\a#1#{#1}
```

calling it as `\a 10` will give a `runaway argument error` whereas calling it as `\a{12}`, will compile with no trouble.

I struggled to find a practical application for such macros even after looking at TeX by Topic, TeXbook and LaTeX source.

Here is my take on it, create some commands to typeset and do some calculations for fractions, as for example those found in basic arithmetic texbooks. You type this,

```
\[\FRAC ADD{3}{8}+{1}{7}\]
\[\FRAC SUB{5}{8}-{1}{7}\]
\[\FRAC MUL{5}{8}x{13}{1201}\]
```

and you get this:

[image]

Here is the code,

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
%% macro factory
\def\FRAC#1#{\csname #1\endcsname}
%% add
\def\ADD#1#2+#3#4{%
  \frac{#1}{#2}+\frac{#3}{#4}=
  \frac{\the\numexpr(#4*#1)+(#3*#2)}{\the\numexpr#2*#4}
}
%% subtract
\def\SUB#1#2-#3#4{%ok top
  \frac{#1}{#2}-\frac{#3}{#4}=
  \frac{\the\numexpr(#4*#1)-(#3*#2)}{\the\numexpr(#2*#4)}
}
%% multiply
\def\MUL#1#2x#3#4{%
  \frac{#1}{#2}\times\frac{#3}{#4}=
  \frac{\the\numexpr(#1*#3)}
  {\the\numexpr#2*#4}
}
%% testing
\[\FRAC ADD{3}{8}+{1}{7}\]
\[\FRAC SUB{5}{8}-{1}{7}\]
\[\FRAC MUL{5}{8}x{13}{1201}\]
\end{document}
```

**Are there any practical applications for such macros? Are there any special precautions one should take? Why would Knuth include this facility in the first place?**

Comment: This is an older question, but here's a recent answer that uses this technique: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85033/colored-symbols

Comment: @ScottH. Heiko magic:) thanks for the pointer. Feel free to edit my question and add the link in somehow, it can be very useful for reference.

Comment: Related: [“Grab to #{” macro arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39525/5764)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This trick of catching until the first open brace can be used in many situations.

- As other posters said, it allows to catch an optional argument expandably if it is not the last. It is possible in principle to get this to be fully robust with respect to nesting, but not implemented yet.
- It can be used to parse the body of a definition provided by the user, to change it to fit your purposes while keeping a natural syntax. (More on parsing def below.)
- I've used this trick primarily to parse a token list expandably without losing any brace. For instance,

  - to expandably uppercase or lowercase a given string (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/are-there-purely-expandable-variants-of-makeuppercase/10806#10806))
  - to fully expand a token list expandably (almost as well as the luatex primitive `\expanded` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/expandable-full-expansion-of-tokens-that-preserves-catcodes/11119#11119))
  - to expand tokens selectively, or in the [reverse order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11184/reversing-the-order-of-expansion/11244#11244)
  - to write a primitive macro expander (i.e. take a file, and expand user-defined macros)

  so basically any situation where you need to be careful with braces, but cannot use `\futurelet`.

This trick only works if there is only one character with catcode 1 (begin group character). Also, we need to be able to put a sentinel at the end of the token list that we are manipulating: otherwise, in the absence of opening brace, we would get a runaway argument.

On parsing a definition: say that you want to give the user an easy way of defining a macro which possibly takes arguments, and always produces a boxed math result. Say that you also want the parameter text to be arbitrary. Either you let the user do everything, or you parse the definition using the trick you ask about.

```
%non-user-friendly
\def\foo_#1^#2#3#4{\fbox{$\sum_{#1}^{#2} \frac{#3}{#4}$}}

%more user friendly (perhaps)
\boxeddef\foo_#1^#2#3#4{\sum_{#1}^{#2} \frac{#3}{#4}}
```

To do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\boxeddef#1#2#{\boxeddef@aux{#1}{#2}}
\def\boxeddef@aux#1#2#3{\def#1#2{\fbox{$#3$}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\def\foo#1#2#3#4{\fbox{$\sum_{#1}^{#2} \frac{#3}{#4}$}}
\boxeddef\foo_#1^#2#3#4{\sum_{#1}^{#2} \frac{#3}{#4}}
\[
\foo_{a}^{b}{C}{D}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22):

The `#{` trick can allow to make macros which behave somewhat like `\hbox{...}`, in the sense that they can have, for example, verbatim inside their argument (also, the argument is not read beforehand). There’s a nice example in the Tugboat article [The TeX Hierarchy](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb15-1/tb42arseneau.pdf) (Volume 15, 1994, p. 7-9):

[image: Programming style comparison]

Compared to the Wizard’s version, the Guru’s use of `#{` makes sure that the character eaten by `\let\next=` will always be a brace, never something else.

Comment: @Philippe: Just to make sure I'm getting it: the `\let\next=` just serves the purpose to eat the opening `{` of `\bold{...}`, correct?

Comment: @Hendrik: yes, and the `\bgroup` is here to match the closing brace of `\bold{...}`.

Comment: @Philippe: What about making the command behave like `\toks` assignments, which expand whatever lies between them and a begin-group token? `\def\bold{\expandafter\boldaux\romannumeral-`\0}` and `\def\boldaux#{\bgroup\bf\let\next= }` Also, using a `\futurelet` test might be better if we want `\bold a` to work.

Comment: @Bruno: `\toks`-like behaviour is a good idea. It allows to write, for example, `\bold\bbgroup...\egroup` where `\def\bbgroup{\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi}`, mimicking things like `\hbox\bgroup...\egroup`.

Comment: @Philippe: a simpler way to get `\bold\bgroup...\egroup` to work (plus the `\toks`-like expansion) is to replace `\def\boldaux{\futurelet\next\boldauxii}` and `\def\boldauxii{\ifx\next\bgroup\else\ERROR\fi \bgroup\bf\let\next= }`. Ok, it's getting messy `:)`.

Comment: @Philippe Goutet ... Capo di Guru : digs out a the _only_ article in TUGboat listing an example of `#{`, thanks :)

Comment: I can't upvote this enough.  However, I don't understand why the Guru's version has a space after the `=`.

Comment: @Ryan: I suppose the reason is that the guru knows that the space after a `\let...=` is optional, but if it's missing, it becomes impossible to detect if a space token is following the macro. But in this particular case, as we are not interested in the next token and since the syntax `\def\macro#{` will give an error if `\macro` is followed by a real space (as opposed to a space eaten by the macro reading mechanism), I don't think the space after `\let` is necessary. I'm not 100% sure, so maybe you should ask a new question on this to have more opinions.

Comment: I wonder what is happening with: `\def\bold#{\bgroup\bf\let\next= }\halign{\bold{#}\crcr test}\bye`.

Comment: @morbusg: Nice catch. From tracing things up, it seems that the `\cr` is seen before the end brace, but I don't know enough about the inner workings of `\halign` to tell you more (although `\def\bold#{\bgroup\bf\let\next= }\halign{\bold{{#}}\cr test\cr}\bye` does work). You should ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 14):

an example from latex.ltx

```
\def\usepackage#1#{%
  \@latex@error
    {\noexpand \usepackage before \string\documentclass}%
    {\noexpand \usepackage may only appear in the document
      preamble, i.e.,\MessageBreak
      between \noexpand\documentclass and
      \string\begin{document}.}%
  \@gobble}
```

with the argument setting you can handle optional arguments, eg `\usepackage[foo]{bar}` without defining the different cases

Answer (score 10):

Reading everything up the opening `{` as argument like `\def\A#1#{...}` would do, it is not very common, but useful when you want to read optional arguments of macro which normal argument must start with `{` anyway. This can be very useful in cases when the macro should be **fully expandable** and therefore `\futurelet` (used by `\@ifnextchar`) can't be used.

Funnily, I just started to use this TeX feature this week:
In my up-coming package 'filemod' I define expandable and non-expandable macros to read and compare file modification dates.
The expandable implementation of `\filemodNewest` takes an optional argument and list of file names `{{filename1}{filename2}...{filename3}}` and expands the the name of the newest file. The `#{` syntax is used to read the potential optional argument (a number in this case):

```
\def\filemodNewest#1#{%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\@filemodNewest
  \csname
    @%
  \ifx\@nnil#1\@nnil
    first%
  \else
    second%
  \fi
    oftwo%
  \endcsname
    {[\filemodcmpdefault]}%
    {#1}%
}
```

It should be noted that this works only for simple optional arguments which do not include braces. This excludes e.g. complex PGF keys etc.

Also the `etextools` defines another way of expandable macros with optional arguments using eTeX `\detokenize`.

Comment: it is possible to extend this expandable parsing of optional arguments in a fully robust way, as long as the last argument is a brace group (assuming that there is only one character with catcode 1). That's on my todo list for Joseph's xparse.

Comment: @Reader: If you find the use of `\csname ... \endcsname` funny, have a look at the [rest of the code](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/general/browser/filemod/dev/filemod.dtx) where `\csname` is used to [recursive expand](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/general/browser/filemod/dev/filemod.dtx#L675) parts of the compare loop :-)

Comment: @Bruno: `xparse` is not mine: I just revisited the code from stuff others had written! (See also my comments about the limitation of `{` and on trailing optional arguments: I suspect `\futurelet` is the only truly robust approach, but am happy to be proved wrong.)

Comment: @Joseph: After studying TeX's mouth for a while, I believe that you are right on this. The current xparse chokes in some cases with optional argumentsdelimited by implicit characters. More on this by email.

Answer (score 6):

I just used this construction in my expandable sanitizer: [Can one define an expandable command that removes control sequences from its argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34029/can-one-define-an-expandable-command-that-removes-control-sequences-from-its-arg/34064#34064).  The purpose there is so that I can parse some arbitrary (well-formed) input for the first group it contains, without actually entering the group.  Without `\futurelet` or `\catcode` changes, it's impossible to grab a single brace token, but this way, I can expand *up until* a group, leaving the braces there, and then continue processing with the sure knowledge that the next thing on the menu is a group.  It has exactly the same purpose as `\futurelet` for this one token.

Comment: I read your answer in the post you quote. It's an amazing piece of code.

Answer (score 5):

I use this possibility in the next case. I can't use delimiters like () because the parenthesis are nested. With

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\def\macro#1#{%
  <#1>\par
  \macrobis
}
\def\macrobis#1{and <#1>}

\begin{document}
\macro(exp(1),ln(2)){A}
\end{document}
```

The first #1 catches `(exp(1),ln(2))`

[image]

Comment: As I recently got told here `xparse` is able to parse `()` or `[]` arguments in an way so that they can be properly nested. But for simpler macros this way is much faster.

Comment: @Martin Yes I know and  you are right. The method is more direct and much faster like you said. My english language is poor so I have some difficulties to explain exactly how useful is this method.

Comment: @Martin: One issue with the `#` method is that it only works for whatever token was catcode 1 at definition time. Not a problem for almost all applications, but if we get `xparse` right as part of LaTeX3 then this is something that might be important. It's also no good for something that requires the _last_ argument is optional (for example `\break`).