# Hyphenation when using \verb command

Tags: macros, line-breaking, verbatim, hyphenation, typewriter

I'm having a problem using `\verb` command.

Usually when I want some verbatim font in the current line (not in a new paragraph) I use the `\verb` command, not the `verbatim` environment.

So, when I use something like `\verb"HereSomeLongText"` no hyphenation is done, so I get my text out of page margins.

How I can get hyphenation inside `\verb`? Please note that I want inline (inside the same line) verbatim like text.

Here is some minimal (non) working example where you can see the problem described.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2.2cm,height=25cm]{geometry}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font=`\-}

\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some TeX example of text  that looks nice, but when 
I Want to type some text like  \verb"myDataFileLongName.csv" using the
verb command, there is no hyphenation nor like break adequately, so the
text inside the verb command get out of the page margins.

\\[0.25cm] So I would appreciate so much any help in order to solve this 
problem. Thanks, thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks, 
thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  
thanks,  thanks,  thanks,  thanks.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico Well, with the standard setup, LaTeX *doesn't* hyphenate words in typewriter type: `\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt

Comment: @egreg I edited my post in order to provide a minimal working example. I read the submitted link, but I cant find the solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hyphenating a file name is not really a good thing: the reader won't know for sure if the hyphen is part of the name or not. Consider the `\path` command of the `url` package.

Comment: @egreg First all, thanks for your help. I appreciate it so much. The file name was only an (bad) example of the unexpected behavior in \verb.

Answer (score 3):

I can't recommend hyphenating a file name, because this introduces an ambiguity: does the hyphen belong to the name or not?

You may consider using the `\path` command provided by the `url` package, by supplementing it with code allowing it to break before capital letters, for instance:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2.2cm,height=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url,etoolbox}
\appto\UrlSpecials{%
  \do\F{\penalty0 \mathchar`\F }%
  \do\L{\penalty0 \mathchar`\L }%
  \do\N{\penalty0 \mathchar`\N }%
}
\begin{document}
Here is some TeX example of text  that looks nice, but when
I Want to type some text like  \path{myDataFileLongName.csv} using the
verb command, there is no hyphenation nor like break adequately, so the
text inside the verb command get out of the page margins.

\end{document}
```

I didn't add all capital letters, do it if you want, or judge from your real cases what's the real need.

[image]

The `\path` command (and also `\url`) works by cleverly exploiting TeX's math mode features. It would be too long to describe completely how it works; for this application, we can make use of the `\UrlSpecials` list macro; the characters contained in the list are made (locally) math active and so their appearance triggers substitution with the prescribed replacement text.

With the proposed code, `F` will become `` \penalty0 \mathchar`\F `` (saying `\penalty0 F` would enter an infinite loop, but `` \mathchar`\F `` is safe): the penalty will allow a line break *before* the `F`.

If you don't want to globally modify the `\path` command, you can add to the `\UrlSpecials` list only locally inside the working of a new command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2.2cm,height=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url,etoolbox}

\let\breaktt\path
\patchcmd{\breaktt}
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\apptourlspecials}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\apptourlspecials}{%
  \appto\UrlSpecials{%
    % add to this list
    \do\F{\penalty0 \mathchar`\F }%
    \do\L{\penalty0 \mathchar`\L }%
    \do\N{\penalty0 \mathchar`\N }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
Here is some TeX example of text  that looks nice, but when
I Want to type some text like  \breaktt{myDataFileLongName.csv} using the
verb command, there is no hyphenation nor like break adequately, so the
text inside the verb command get out of the page margins.

\end{document}
```

The command `\path` expands to `\leavevmode\begingroup\urlstyle{tt}\Url`, so we define `\breaktt` to do the same but we also add something just after `\begingroup`, precisely the addition to the list `\UrlSpecials` we need. In this way `\path` and `\url` will behave as before.

Comment: Dear @egreg. Your solution works fine for my purposes, and that is great for me. I would like to know how your solution works, in order to get into a deep knowledge of LaTeX.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can force hyphenation by using `\texttt` instead of `\verb`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
Here is some TeX example of text that looks nice, but when
I type \verb!Sonification! using the
verb command, there is no hyphenation nor like break adequately, so the
text inside the verb command get out of the page margins.

Here is some TeX example of text that looks nice, but when
I type \texttt{Soni\-fi\-cation} using the
verb command, there is no hyphenation nor like break adequately, so the
text inside the verb command get out of the page margins.
\end{document}
```

[image]