# Is there a way to suppress the black boxes in the margin only?

Tags: margins, indexing, draft

I want index entries to be visible in the margins. We are using the `index`package for multiple indexes. This package provides the option to display the index entries in the margin. For some cases I get a black box. I do not want to disable the black boxes all together since they are needed for normal text, but I do not want to see them with the index entries. Is there a way to disable them locally?

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ papersize={170mm,240mm}
        ,top=27.4mm 
        ,inner=20mm 
        ,outer=25mm
                    ,marginparwidth=50pt
        ]{geometry}

\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\proofmodetrue

\begin{document}

~
\newpage
This is some text and there is some index\index{package!lsp-gb4e} entry.

\end{document}
```

Edit: An alternative would be to make LaTeX break these long items in the margin and put them into two lines. Is this possible?

Comment: That box should disappear once you switch from `draft` to `final`. It's just there to alert you to the problem.

Comment: Yes, I know. But there is no problem in terms of overfull boxes that I have to be alerted of as far as the margin notes are concerned, since they will be gone in the `final`version as well. I want to be in `draft` mode and see the black boxes for normal text, but not in the margins. Actually the boxes are not in the margins but cover the main text. This is the reason why I want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `\indexproofstyle` for example to use a smaller, non typewriter, font and make the marginpar ragged right.  This will avoid many of the overfull boxes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[papersize={170mm,240mm}
  ,top=27.4mm
  ,inner=20mm, 
  ,outer=25mm
  ,marginparwidth=50pt
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\proofmodetrue
\indexproofstyle{\raggedright\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

~
\newpage
This is some text and there is some index\index{package!lsp-gb4e} entry.

\end{document}
```

If you just wish to switch off the black boxes, then you could write

```
\indexproofstyle{\setlength{\overfullrule}{0pt}\footnotesize\ttfamily}
```

[image: Sample tt]

Note the typewriter fonts don't hyphenate by default.  See [How to automatically hyphenate within \texttt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44361/15925) for some ways to change this.

Comment: Damn, I misunderstood the question. I deleted my answer. +1 for yours, that's a good approach!

Comment: Thanks! Did not realize that one can put arbitrary stuff into \indexproofstyle.