# Example about hyphenation with ttfamily font

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, minipage

Reading [How to automatically hyphenate within \texttt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt) I could not figure it out how to make the `ttfamily` to hyphenate automatically. The text on the question [wordbreaking, justification and ttfamily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171278/wordbreaking-justification-and-ttfamily) is not hyphenated. Is there an example about hyphenation with `ttfamily`?

I tried adding `` \hyphenchar\font=`\-\relax `` as suggested by @Skillmon on [Minipage/framebox text is not justified and throws several Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386652/minipage-framebox-text-is-not-justified-and-throws-several-underfull-hbox-badn) comment, but it still not justified/hyphenated:

```
\documentclass[10pt,openright,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\hyphenchar\font=`\-\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\hspace*{1cm}
{Catalogação na fonte pela Biblioteca Universitária da Universidade
Universitária da Universidade.}

\framebox[\textwidth]
{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

        \ttfamily
        Lembre-se: a ficha de identificação da obra elaborada pelo autor deve constar no
        verso da folha de rosto de teses e dissertações de modo a possibilitar sua
        representação precisa pelas informações de autor, título, local, data, número de
        folhas, assunto, etc.

    \end{minipage}
}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You did not read the answer to the linked question [wordbreaking, justification and ttfamily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171278/wordbreaking-justification-and-ttfamily) very carefully did you? You have to alter the `\ttfamily` macro (or invoke the changes in a second macro just after it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the complete added code.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,openright,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

%THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART   % <=========================================
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\origttfamily\ttfamily
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ttfamily}{%
  \origttfamily
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-\relax
  \fontdimen3\font=.25em\relax
  \fontdimen4\font=.167em\relax
  \fontdimen7\font=.167em\relax
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\vttfamily{%
  \not@math@alphabet\vttfamily\relax
  \fontfamily{cmvtt}% cmvtt (Computer Modern) or lmvtt (Latin Modern)
  \selectfont
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textvtt}{\vttfamily}
\makeatother % <=========================================================

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\hspace*{1cm}
{Catalogação na fonte pela Biblioteca Universitária da Universidade
Universitária da Universidade.}

\framebox[\textwidth]
{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

        \ttfamily
        Lembre-se: a ficha de identificação da obra elaborada pelo autor deve constar no
        verso da folha de rosto de teses e dissertações de modo a possibilitar sua
        representação precisa pelas informações de autor, título, local, data, número de
        folhas, assunto, etc.

    \end{minipage}
}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]