# How can I use `\texttt{Some text}` with automatic hyphenation?

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, hyphenation, typewriter, restructured-text

On the question [How to automatically hyphenate within \texttt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt) is explained a lot of things, but I could not understand, or at make it work some things.

On the question [Example about hyphenation with ttfamily font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386665/example-about-hyphenation-with-ttfamily-font) I is showed to to apply the `ttfont` to all text, for example:

```
\ttfamily
Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family: pcr, series: m, 
shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)
```

But how can I wrap it around some words like `\texttt{Some text}` or an environment?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\texttt{Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family: pcr, series: m, shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)}

\begin{texttt}
Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family: pcr, series: m, shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)
\end{texttt}

\end{document}
```

The `texttt` is not hyphenating and it generation the warnings:

```
test2.tex:182: Overfull \hbox (11.9992pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--183[]\T1/lmtt/m/n/10 Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family:
test2.tex:182: Overfull \hbox (33.7491pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--183\T1/lmtt/m/n/10 pcr, series: m, shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)
```

[image]

---

Related:

1. [Line break in texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219445/line-break-in-texttt)
2. [wordbreaking, justification and ttfamily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171278/wordbreaking-justification-and-ttfamily)

Comment: You don't need to do anything special for \texttt. If you change the settings for `\ttfamily` as shown in the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386665/example-about-hyphenation-with-ttfamily-font it will affect `\texttt` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386665/example-about-hyphenation-with-ttfamily-font) as Ulrike said, which is basically the present question, you could have an easier solution using `fontspec` and compiling with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing


\fontspec{Latin Modern Mono}\footnotesize  

\lipsum[1-3]

\rmfamily


\lipsum[1-3]



\end{document}
```

Comment: This only works for the \fontspec{Latin Modern Mono) and not with \ttfamily or \texttt as asked by the OP.

Comment: Yes, but it works for his purposes, which is to write hyphenated / justified paragraphs in a monospaced font.

Comment: I have no idea what are the purposes of the question, imho this is rather unclear, but the title of the question is explicitly about `\texttt{}` and I only wanted to make clear that your answer doesn't address this point.