# Why the environment ttfamily is hyphenated, but macro ttfamily is not hyphenating?

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, hyphenation, typewriter

I tried copying the example from [Example about hyphenation with ttfamily font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386665/example-about-hyphenation-with-ttfamily-font) and using the name `ttfamily` as `\ttfamily{Some text}` and `\begin{ttfamily}` & `\end{ttfamily}`.

However why the first line using the macro `ttfamily` is not hyphenated, but the second using the environment `\begin{ttfamily}` is hyphenated?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

%THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART   % <=========================================
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\origttfamily\ttfamily
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ttfamily}{%
  \origttfamily
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-\relax
  \fontdimen3\font=.25em\relax
  \fontdimen4\font=.167em\relax
  \fontdimen7\font=.167em\relax
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\vttfamily{%
  \not@math@alphabet\vttfamily\relax
  \fontfamily{cmvtt}% cmvtt (Computer Modern) or lmvtt (Latin Modern)
  \selectfont
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textvtt}{\vttfamily}
\makeatother % <=========================================================

\begin{document}

    \frenchspacing
    \ttfamily{Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family: pcr, series: m,
    shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)}

    \bigskip

    \begin{ttfamily}
        Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family: pcr, series: m,
        shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)
    \end{ttfamily}

\end{document}
```

On the question [How can I use `\texttt{Some text}` with automatic hyphenation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387581/how-can-i-use-textttsome-text-with-automatic-hyphenation) we can see the same text without the `tttext` hyphenation, it causing `Overfull \hbox`:

[image]

```
test2.tex:182: Overfull \hbox (11.9992pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--183[]\T1/lmtt/m/n/10 Typewriter/teletype family - (encoding: T1, family:
test2.tex:182: Overfull \hbox (33.7491pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--183\T1/lmtt/m/n/10 pcr, series: m, shape: n, size: 10.5, baseline: 11.0pt)
```

Comment: First, proper group-limited syntax would be `{\ttfamily Some text}` and not `\ttfamily{Some text}.`  That is, `\ttfamily` takes no argument (perhaps you are confusing it with `\texttt{}`).  Not that that fixes your problem.

Comment: If I comment out your redefinition of `\ttfamily`, the two examples typeset identically.

Comment: If I comment out just the `\fontdimen4\font=.167em\relax` part of your redefinition, both paragraphs hyphenate.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it seems a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definitions, doing

```
{\ttfamily text}
```

and

```
\begin{ttfamily}text\end{ttfamily}
```

is exactly the same. Indeed the output of the following examples is exactly the same.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\origttfamily\ttfamily
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ttfamily}{%
  \origttfamily
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-\relax
  \fontdimen3\font=.25em\relax
  \fontdimen4\font=.167em\relax
  \fontdimen7\font=.167em\relax
}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing

{\ttfamily 
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\bigskip

\begin{ttfamily}
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
\end{ttfamily}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes**

1. `\ttfamily{...}` is wrong, in the sense that the font will be in typewriter type also after `}`.
2. The space after `\begin{ttfamily}` (the end-of-line, to be precise) is ignored because it is scanned when TeX is between paragraphs. It wouldn't be if `\begin{ttfamily}` is scanned in paragraph mode.
3. Avoid using pseudoenvironments like these.