# How to hyphenate automatically within \texttt when using T1 encoding and lmodern

Tags: fonts, hyphenation, typewriter

I was looking for a way to enable hyphenation within `\texttt`.
I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt) and it seemed perfect: simple and useful to many people.

I chose to enable hyphenation globally in `\texttt` and as suggested there, I added the following line:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\hyphenchar\font=`\-}
```

Unfortunately, it did not work and had an undesired side-effect: the typewriter font was no longer used inside `\texttt` and the following error appeared in the console output:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

This error pointed me right on track: I always use the T1 encoding and lmodern fonts in my LaTeX documents:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

and as soon as I commented out those lines, everything worked fine.

Is there a way to adapt the original answer to this case as well?
I'd have added a comment to that post, but unfortunately I still haven't sufficient reputation to do that.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be solved in a different way, which requires loading the font definition file manually and changing the hyphenchar before any font of that family is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\input{t1lmtt.fd}
\@namedef{T1+lmtt}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\ttfamily
  \hspace{0pt}hyphenation in typewriter type 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One of the duties of `\DeclareFontFamily{enc}{fam}{code}` is to define `\enc+fam` to expand to `code`. The control sequence `\enc+fam` is not directly usable because of `+`, so `\@namedef` (which is `\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname`) can be used. Since the normal declaration is

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{lmtt}{\hyphenchar=-1 }
```

which does

```
\@namedef{T1+lmtt}{\hyphenchar=-1 }
```

we counteract it by doing

```
\@namedef{T1+lmtt}{}
```

The `code` is used as soon as a font shape relative to font family is selected and permanently attached to the chosen font. So it's important that the redefinition happens before any font is actually selected.

Comment: What is the `\@namedef` doing exactly, if you don't mind answering?

Comment: @cfr Added an explanation

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg, I chose this answer as correct because of the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Franks answer is missing an important point: When you declare a font family in your preamble latex no longer tries to input the .fd-file and so all other font declarations are lost. You can input them before doing the change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\input{t1lmtt.fd}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\hyphenchar\font=`\-}


\begin{document}
\ttfamily abc \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Or alternatively:

```
\ttfamily
\hyphenchar\font=`\-
\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\hyphenchar\font=`\-}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ulrike, your answer is very similar to @egreg's, and I chose his for the sake of completeness.