# Monospace (typewriter) fonts do not respect margins

Tags: formatting, margins, typewriter

I am trying to use a typewriter font (TXTT) in a document, but it consistently overruns the margins. I don't know if this is expected or if I am making a mistake in my document.

An MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}

% Load packages
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, urlcolor = blue, linkcolor = black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{itemsep=0.05em}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% TXTT typewriter font
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Formatting matters
\setlength\parskip{1em}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
\renewcommand\contentsname{} % the empty ToC name
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

% =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's expected. I think selection teletype font turns off hyphenation. A wider text block and/or smaller type size can help, as can `\sloppy`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's a bummer because for this use-case the aesthetic is really nice. Cheers!

Comment: You might have better results with a proportional tt font (e.g., Latin Modern Mono Proportional) or a typewriter-esque slab serif like Computer Concrete.

Comment: you can enable hyphenation, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204420/2388, but monospaced typewriter fonts don't go well together with justified text, better use \raggedright.

Comment: use `\raggedright`  with fixed width space and no hyphenation it is literally impossible to justify the text margins.

Comment: Using `\raggedright` also did the trick. I wasn't fixated on keeping the text justified, so this works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load yourself the font definition file, modifying it to

1. allow hyphenation, so removing `\hyphenchar\font=\m@ne`;
2. define a stretchability for each of the fonts;
3. define a shrinkability for each of the fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}

% Load packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% TXTT font
\newcommand{\fixfontdimens}{%
  \fontdimen3\font=0.5\fontdimen2\font
  \fontdimen4\font=0.2\fontdimen2\font
}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{txtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{<->t1xtt}{\fixfontdimens}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{m}{sc}{<->t1xttsc}{\fixfontdimens}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{m}{sl}{<->t1xttsl}{\fixfontdimens}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{m}{it}{<->ssub * txtt/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{m}{ui}{<->ssub * txtt/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{<->t1xbtt}{\fixfontdimens}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{bx}{sc}{<->t1xbttsc}{\fixfontdimens}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{bx}{sl}{<->t1xbttsl}{\fixfontdimens}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{bx}{ui}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{b}{n}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{b}{sc}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{b}{it}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txtt}{b}{ui}{<->ssub * txtt/bx/ui}{}

\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\textit{\kant[1][1-3]}

\textbf{\kant[1][4-6]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much.