# Break on special characters in inline verbatim

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, hyphenation

I'm using Pandoc to generate LaTeX. My text contains inline code spans (backticks in markdown) that are rendered as `\texttt{...}` in TeX. However, some of them are quite long and overflow the line, for example this paragraph:

```
In the context of the variables
\texttt{\{"query": "mycelium", "number": 100\}}, this would be expanded to
the URI \texttt{http://www.example.com/foo?query=mycelium\&number=100}.
```

I cannot change the generated code since that would affect the output when rendering to HTML.

I tried to insert a unicode zero-width space, but pdflatex chokes on that. I cannot use TeX commands inside the verbatim environment since Pandoc escapes all those before outputting them inside a `\texttt`:

```
$ echo 'my `code\bar`' | pandoc -t latex
my \texttt{code\textbackslash{}bar}
```

So what I'm looking for is a TeX command that redefines `\texttt` to reflow the line when it's too long. Or alternatively, a command to break all words that are too long on special characters like `?=%&`.

**Edit**: I tried the following but it doesn't have any effect (63 being the decimal ascii code point for `?`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % with or without this...

% ... either of the following don't work:
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font=63}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\mytexttt}{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=63\relax}

\begin{document}

In the context of the variables
\texttt{\{"query": "mycelium", "number": 100\}}, this would be expanded to
the very long long long URI \texttt{http://www.example.com/foo?query=mycelium\&number=100}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should rather teach Pandoc to use `\url` (package `url` or `hyperref`) instead of `\texttt` for URLs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically hyphenate within \texttt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt)

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks, indeed I didn't find that question before. However, I tried it with no effect (see my edited question). I must be missing something...

Comment: Pandoc can use `fancyvrb` and also lets you specify your own TeX template (#14 at [Pandoc - Demos](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html), so I'm not sure why it's using `\texttt` for inline code anyway.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I'm guessing it's using `fancyvrb` only for special situations, and templates don't affect the stuff that it puts where the `$body$` variable is.

Comment: @egreg I'm not actually looking for a link (pandoc actually uses `hyperref` for those). I just want the `\texttt` to wrap on lines.

Comment: @mb21 `\url` has facilities for breaking at various points in the URI.

Comment: @egreg right, however I'd like to break any long text in a `\texttt` (like e.g. JSON without spaces), not just urls.

Comment: `url` package provides the `\url` command which is just a version of verbatim allowing breaks.  The corresponding command with `hyperref` is `\nolinkurl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example can't break at the ? because the first definition defines the hyphenchar for cmtt in T1 encoding (and you use lmodern) and the second defines `\mytexttt` but your document uses `\texttt`.

If you

- replace `\texttt` with `\mytexttt`
- or drop lmodern and use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
- or drop lmodern and use
  `\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font=63}`

then your example works for me (albeit with an overfull box as the ? comes too late.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're completely right. I guess I was almost there when I despaired :)