# Breaking Typewriter-styled Detokenized Text

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter, detokenize

The goal is to have snake_cased elements typewriter-styled breaking properly. I am using `\detokenize` rather than simply `\_` because otherwise the snake_casing looks wrong, namely like this:

[image: \textt{is_normalized}]

rather than like this

[image: \texttt{\detokenize{is_normalized}}]

But LaTeX will not break them. Here is a basic example:

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}
\sloppy


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\isnormalized}[1]{
\texttt{\detokenize{is_normalized}}(\ensuremath{#1})
}

\newcommand{\atomincons}[2]{
\texttt{\detokenize{is_atomically_inconsistent}}(\ensuremath{#1,#2})
}

\newcommand{\containsnodiamond}[1]{
\texttt{\detokenize{contains_no_diamond}}(\ensuremath{#1})
}

\newcommand{\containsonlyliterals}[1]{
\texttt{\detokenize{contains_only_literals}}(\ensuremath{#1})
}

\newcommand{\prop}{\textsc{prop}}


The procedures do as their names say. Specifically, \atomincons{\Delta}{\prop} returns \textbf{1}
if there exist both $p$ and $\neg p$ in $\Delta$ for some propositional letter
$p\in\prop$ and returns \textbf{0} otherwise. \containsonlyliterals{\Delta} returns \textbf{1} if $\Delta$ contains only atomic
literals and \textbf{0} otherwise. \containsnodiamond{\Delta} returns
\textbf{1} if there is no formula of the form $\langle a\rangle \varphi'$ in
$\Delta$ and \textbf{0} otherwise. Note that \isnormalized{\Delta},
\containsonlyliterals{\Delta} and \containsnodiamond{\Delta} runs in time linear
in the size of the set $\Delta$ while \atomincons{\Delta}{\prop} takes time at
most quadratic in the size of $\Delta$.


\end{document}
```

Removing the `draft` option and `\sloppy` makes the problem clearer.

Comment: tokenization isn't involved it is just the font setup see this possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt

Comment: You are right. Forgot to test that. I should probably delete the question?

Comment: But with detokenize I cannot use an hypen character. Is the linked solution working anyway?

Comment: what do you mean by can't use the hyphen character ( `\-` obviously doesn't work but it doesn't affect automatic hyphenation) Probably I would leave breaking disabled between letters and just allow it after `_` (and don't add a hyphen at all

Comment: But if I do: \DeclareTextFontCommand{\mytexttt}{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=-1\relax}, \newcommand{\atomincons}[2]{
\mytexttt{\detokenize{is_atomically_inconsistent}}(\ensuremath{#1,#2})
}, then there is still no automatic hyphenation.

Comment: you'd have to make  `_` a letter as well (`\lccode \`\_=\`\_` would do, but see alternative approach I just posted as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than allow hyphenation I would just allow things to break after `_` most easily using `url` package. Also beware your definitions added a lot of spurious white space from ends of lines in the definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{url}


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\isnormalized}[1]{%
\path{is_normalized}($#1$)%
}

\newcommand{\atomincons}[2]{%
\path{is_atomically_inconsistent}($#1,#2$)%
}

\newcommand{\containsnodiamond}[1]{%
\path{contains_no_diamond}($#1$)%
}

\newcommand{\containsonlyliterals}[1]{%
\path{contains_only_literals}($#1$)%
}

\newcommand{\prop}{\textsc{prop}}


The procedures do as their names say. Specifically, \atomincons{\Delta}{\prop} returns \textbf{1}
if there exist both $p$ and $\neg p$ in $\Delta$ for some propositional letter
$p\in\prop$ and returns \textbf{0} otherwise. \containsonlyliterals{\Delta} returns \textbf{1} if $\Delta$ contains only atomic
literals and \textbf{0} otherwise. \containsnodiamond{\Delta} returns
\textbf{1} if there is no formula of the form $\langle a\rangle \varphi'$ in
$\Delta$ and \textbf{0} otherwise. Note that \isnormalized{\Delta},
\containsonlyliterals{\Delta} and \containsnodiamond{\Delta} runs in time linear
in the size of the set $\Delta$ while \atomincons{\Delta}{\prop} takes time at
most quadratic in the size of $\Delta$.


\end{document}
```