# Highlighting Text with Background Color

Tags: spacing, color, tcolorbox, highlighting, backgrounds

I'm trying to **highlight text** using the **`\texttt` font** and a **background color** (pretty much like the *highlighting on StackExchange* [i.e., `this`]. I already tried it **using a `colorbox`**, it *doesn't support line breaks* though, resulting in:

[image]

Alternatively, I found a **package called `soul`** for highlighting, but in my opinion it's **visually not as appealing** as the colorbox because of the **missing padding**, it will look like this:

[image]

On the left is the colorbox, on the right is the `soul` package.

My coding:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.925, 0.925, 0.925}
\sethlcolor{lightgrey}

\newcommand{\codebox}[1]{\texttt{\colorbox{lightgrey}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\codebox2}[1]{\texttt{\hl{#1}}}
```

Any ideas how to overcome these caveats?

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments below `\texttt` doesn't support line breaks as well which makes the problem even worse.

Comment: Since `\texttt{}` does not break anyway, this is twice  worsed idea to use `\colorbox` **and** `\texttt`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for this hint. But, so what do you recommend if I want that font, a background color with nice padding/margin and correct line breaking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soul doesn't support adjusting the sizes that determine the placement of its highlight box.

By looking at its code, I redefined one of its internal macros. I also used the trick from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44362/99343).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz} % only to get \foreach

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.925, 0.925, 0.925}
\sethlcolor{lightgrey}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{}{3.5ex}% increased by 1ex
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \dimen@\SOUL@ulthickness
    \dimen@i=-.75ex % increased by -0.25ex
    \advance\dimen@i-.5\dimen@
    \edef\SOUL@uldepth{\the\dimen@i}%
    \let\SOUL@ulcolor\SOUL@stcolor
    \SOUL@ulpreamble
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\codebox}[1]{{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=45\relax\hl{~#1~}}}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
        text text text text text \codebox{extracalifragilisticexpealidocious}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that this may break if the authors of `soul` change their packet's interna and that the large boxes change the line height.

Comment: Wow, what a hack. :) But it changes the font family of the text that is followed by the codebox to the ttfamily. If you try something like this: `\codebox{extracalifragilisticexpealidocious} test test test test test test test`

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas: You're right, I didn't properly test my code. I've added a TeX group in the `\codebox` command to fix this issue. Also note that this command enables hyphenation in all `\ttfamily` text. The linked question has a solution that fixes the issue.