# How to highlight characters both in text and math environments in a flexible way?

Tags: math-mode, color, highlighting, soul

I would like to color the background of characters (word, sentences or math variables) with the same command in text paragraphs and in equations.
The command `\colorbox{color}{some text}` doesn't do the job because it is not able to break lines, and it is not usable with math content.

Then I tried to use the `soul` package as given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297736/46718). This is very close to what I want except it doesn't work within math environment.

Here is a MWE (the problematic part is commented and marked by a red dot on image):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\sethlcolor{gray} 

\begin{document}
This is a long text without highlighting. \hl{This is a long text with highlighting over the line break.} This is a long text without highlighting.

This is an equation with highlighted variable:
$
1+x^2+ %\hl{x^3}
$
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code with red dot]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't, please. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\sethlcolor{gray}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mhl}[1]{%
  \text{\hl{$#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}
This is a long text without highlighting. \hl{This is a long
text $x^3$ with highlighting over the line break.} This is a long
text without highlighting.

This is an equation with highlighted variable:
$
1+x_{\mhl{zz}}^2+\mhl{x^3}
$
\end{document}
```

One might think to make a command that works both in text and in math:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mhl}[1]{%
  \ifmmode\text{\hl{$#1$}}\else\hl{#1}\fi
}
```

[image]

The example shows that the gray background doesn't fully cover the exponent also in the standard version, so it's a `soul` problem.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed! Unfortunately I noticed it doesn't work with a `\phantom` character (error saying "Incomplete \iffalse"). Do you know why?

Comment: @Tobard There are too many possible reasons, without an example.

Comment: Sorry, just add `\mhl{This is a sentence \phantom{word} containing a phantom word.}` in the MWE you gave and you'll have the error. Thanks.

Comment: @Tobard Does it work with `\hl` to begin with? I don't think so.

Comment: Oh you're right, this comes directly from the `soul` package. This may be worth another question, then.

Comment: \hl{For the moving state, speeds of \SI{5}{\km\per\hour} and \SI{20}{\km\per\hour} are considered}. Why it is not working when used as above?