# How to make content written in texttt{} to wraparound the margin?

Tags: typewriter

The content I have written inside the

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
I want the below block to wrap around the margin without overshooting it.  When you compile you can see that it goes beyound the margin. I think it might due some default \texttt{\\texttt} property. 

\texttt{ ( \{ dfadfasfadfa, ddfadfas, dfadfa, dafjakdf, djflakjdfa, kdjflakjdj ,              dkfjadfaaddafa faffadfad fafljfdfadf \}, djfadjfkadfafda,  \{kdfja, akdfjalkd, kdjfaljdfa, kjldajfa \}, dfadfa dfa, dfadfa )}.



\end{document}
```

is going beyond the margin then coming to the next line.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: The text is wide and inserting a line break between words will lead to underfill or overfill. Do you want to allow hyphenation of the text inside `\texttt`? See [How to automatically hyphenate within \texttt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44361/106162). Or do you just want to stop the text overflowing into the margin?

Comment: Justified text in typewriter usually does not make sense and almost always is problematic. I would suggest to put it in a `flushleft` environment or the corresponding environment of package `ragged2e`, if you would like to have hyphenation.