# Colored symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, color

First of all, I apologize if this is a repetitive question. I searched, but couldn't find it. I was wondering if I can change the color of symbols in latex. For example `\ast` always give me a *black symbol*. Is there anyway to change it? (either changing it permanently throughout the document or changing it just once.

Comment: `\textcolor{red}{\ast}`. `\textcolor` works in math mode as well.  To redefine it globally `\let\OldAst\ast` `\renewcommand{\ast}{\textcolor{red}{\OldAst}}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: It works; great! Thank you. I wish you had written it as an answer; then I get to select it as correct answer; just for the future reference. Would you please do that?

Comment: Well, looks like Heiko's answer is a much better solution.  Good to have _real_ experts on this site.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`\textcolor` of package `color` adds a level of curly braces that become a subformula in math mode, destroying the spacing. The following example defines `\mathcolor` that can be used in the same way as `\textcolor`, but without the subformula side effect. It uses `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` instead of the curly braces that do not cause the trouble in math. A grouping level is needed for LaTeX's color handling that restores the color after the group via `\aftergroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand*{\mathcolor}{}
\def\mathcolor#1#{\mathcoloraux{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mathcoloraux}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
$a\ast b$

$a\textcolor{red}{\ast}b$

$a\mathcolor{red}{\ast}b$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The parameter text of `\mathcolor` is `#1#` with a final hash symbol without number. That means all tokens before the next opening curly brace are put into `#1`. In case of `\mathcolor` (or `\textcolor`) this is the optional argument. Without an optional argument `#1` is empty, otherwise it contains the optional argument including the square brackets.

Comment: Would you add an explanation why you need `#1` in the definition of `\mathcolor`?

Comment: @egreg I have updated the answer to add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I had in mind something with `\binrel@` of `amsmath` but it's not as general as your code.