# Interaction of \boldmath and \not

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, color, bold

It seems that using `\boldmath` (or `\bm`) along with the `\not` does not quite work so well.  Here is an example using `\not\subseteq` and `\not\le`
where  the line representing negation does not stretch sufficiently past the end of the symbol.

[image]

### Questions:

- Is there a better way to get bold math, or do I need to resort to my usual *overkill* solution and use `\tikz` to draw the `not` line?
- Is this is known issue with bold math, and are there other known issues with bold math?

### References:

- I am using the solution from [Colored symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85033/colored-symbols-in-latex) for `\MathColor`, the math equivalent for `\textcolor`.
- Followup question: [Automate replacement of `\not` when in `\bm` mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99533/automate-replacenement-of-not-when-in-bm-mode).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85033/colored-symbols-in-latex
\newcommand*{\MathColor}{}
\def\MathColor#1#{\mathcoloraux{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mathcoloraux}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\Expression}{R \not\subseteq T, x \not\le y}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r l}
                  & $\Expression$ \\% This works fine.
\verb|\boldmath|: & {\boldmath $ \Expression$} \\
\verb|\bm|: & \bm{$\Expression$} 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
Test with color
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{r l}
\verb|\MathColor|: & $\MathColor{red}{\Expression}$ \\
\verb|\boldmath|: & {\boldmath $ \MathColor{red}{\Expression}$} \\
\verb|\bm|: & %\par\bm{$\MathColor{\Expression}$}%% ???
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, you might want to add, what you dislike. Yes, the `\not` does not extend that much over the negated symbol, but other than that … Sadly, the `\nsubseteq` macro from the `amssymb` package behaves much worse. The `\bm`-`\Mathcolor` combination works again if you add another set of `{ }` braces around `\MathColor` (potentially harming the spacing, again): `\bm{${\MathColor{red}{\Expression}}$}`

Comment: I don't know where to start about other issues too :) but probably @DavidCarlisle would give the whole picture as he has been recently thinking about alternatives.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Have added that info, and now also include `\not\le`.

Comment: @percuße: Yep, David is _the_ man of `color` around here. :-)  But he does have an unfair advantage.

Comment: Perhaps the package centernot is of help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say that in the end this is a font problem: you need a font with a bold `\nsubseteq` symbol. (Or the `\not` symbol from the bold math font should be longer.) If you don't have appropriate symbols, you can tinker around and manually construct a longer `\not` symbol. I did this in the code below, and it appears that it behaves nicely with `\bm` and `\color`:

[image: output]

Beware: This works with manual kerns that are pixel perfect only for the CM font in `\textstyle`. Note that to have `\bm` work with color, you shouldn't `\bm` the colored math but color the `\bm`ed math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,xcolor}
\newcommand*\longnot{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-0.75mu
    \raisebox{-0.8pt}{$\not$}%
    \mkern1.5mu
    \raisebox{0.8pt}{$\not$}%
    \mkern-0.75mu
    }
  }
\begin{document}
$\bm{A\not\subseteq B}$ versus $\bm{A\longnot\subseteq B}$
\par\smallskip
with color: \color{red}{$\bm{R \longnot\subseteq T,\ x \longnot\le y$}}
\end{document}
```