# Automate replacement of `\not` when in `\bm` mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, color, bold

Hendrik Vogt has provided a `\longnot` macro to alleviate the issues related to
[Interaction of \boldmath and \not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98433/interaction-of-boldmath-and-not). This seems to work fine, but I run into a snag when I try to automatically use `\longnot` instead of the usual `\not` when I am in `\bm` mode.

This seemed like a very simple:

```
\let\not\longnot%
```

or

```
\def\not{\longnot}%
```

but these results in

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]

The MWE as is yields:

[image]

When automated, the last `\subseteq` in red should be using the `\longnot` instead of `\not`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}% Eliminate the need for \noindent
\usepackage{bm,xcolor}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98433/interaction-of-boldmath-and-not
\newcommand*\longnot{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-0.75mu
    \raisebox{-0.8pt}{$\not$}%
    \mkern1.5mu
    \raisebox{0.8pt}{$\not$}%
    \mkern-0.75mu
    }
  }

\newcommand{\ColorRed}[1]{%
    %\let\not\longnot%        Why can I NOT use one of these???
    %\def\not{\longnot}%
    \textcolor{red}{\bm{#1}}%
}%
\begin{document}
$\bm{A\not\subseteq B}$ versus $\bm{A\longnot\subseteq B}$
\par\smallskip
with color: \textcolor{red}{$\bm{R \longnot\subseteq T,\ x \longnot\le y$}}

Replace \verb|\not| with \verb|\longnot| when in \verb|\bm| mode:

$A \not\subseteq B$,
\ColorRed{$A \not\subseteq B$},
$A \not\subseteq B$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the TeX capacity error: put `\let\orignot\not` and replace both `\not` by `\orignot` in the definition of `\longnot`, and after that all put `\let\not\longnot` ?

Comment: yes, as @tohecz says  and -50 for trying to implicate bm in your infinite loop:-)

Comment: Damm!! I had a feeling it was going to be embarrassing, but certainly did not think it was going to be _this much_ of a rookie mistake. @DavidCarlisle: Based on that comment I think I know who I should be blaming for my BM issues. :-)

Comment: You should add some `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in your `\ColorRed` so that the redefinition of `\not` becomes local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `\let\orignot\not` and replace both `\not` by `\orignot` in the definition of `\longnot`, and after that all, put `\let\not\longnot`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}% Eliminate the need for \noindent
\usepackage{bm,xcolor}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98433/interaction-of-boldmath-and-not
\let\orignot\not
\newcommand*\longnot{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-0.75mu
    \raisebox{-0.8pt}{$\orignot$}%
    \mkern1.5mu
    \raisebox{0.8pt}{$\orignot$}%
    \mkern-0.75mu
    }
  }

\newcommand{\ColorRed}[1]{%
    %\let\not\longnot%        Why can I NOT use one of these???
    %\def\not{\longnot}%
    \textcolor{red}{\bm{#1}}%
}%
\begin{document}
$\bm{A\not\subseteq B}$ versus $\bm{A\longnot\subseteq B}$
\par\smallskip
with color: \textcolor{red}{$\bm{R \longnot\subseteq T,\ x \longnot\le y$}}

Replace \verb|\not| with \verb|\longnot| when in \verb|\bm| mode:

$A \not\subseteq B$,
\ColorRed{$A \not\subseteq B$},
$A \not\subseteq B$.
\end{document}
```