# What is this font used by Wiki?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

When we create a LaTeX document, it uses Computer Modern font by default, which is like this:

[image]

But I see that all formulas in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) is in this font, which I think is much more beautiful:
[image]

**What is this font? How can I use it in my LaTeX document?**

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be the boldface version of the Computer Modern math fonts. Just write  `\boldmath` before entering math mode.

Comment: @Bernard - Using `\boldmath` was first reaction too. However, `\boldmath` invokes bold-extended by default, whereas the wikipedia example appears to use "regular-width" bold math fonts.

Comment: @Bernard: I don't think so. If you see this link: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98433/interaction-of-boldmath-and-not), \boldmath is actually much more thick.

Comment: It's probably something you could achieve with a `\pdfliteral` artifact.

Comment: "...the Wiki...". Which wiki?

Comment: @ Werner: This wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: The equation appears to have been converted or created using MathJax.  See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a last resort, you can use `\pdfliteral` (at least in pdflatex and lualatex, IIRC), altough it may not look as good in printing. Just modify the `0.25` bit to your taste.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand*\mathbold[1]{\pdfliteral direct{2 Tr 0.25 w}#1\pdfliteral direct{0 Tr 0 w}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6. \qquad \mathbold{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6.}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I think that what you are showing might be an artifact of the svg rendering.

Comment: Can I use this method to "bold" text? I mean text in Computer Modern font.

Comment: Yes, altough it depends on the pdf viewer / printer, it might not have the same look across all plataforms.

Comment: Can you show me the code I need to "bold" text by this method?

Comment: It's exactly the same, just name the command `\bold` rather than `\mathbold` to have consistency, and you can use it in text or math mode.

Comment: I know this was requested but ... uuuggghhh. Text is worse, though, I think. @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ It would be better to pick a font which is designed with thicker lines etc., if that's what you want. Really, this is going to throw up all kinds of uglinesses and inconsistencies.

Comment: @ cfr: I will certainly like to use another font, but I just can't find one that looks like the above one. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @ Manuel: This is my last inquiry: what code should I use so that all text and formula in my document (from the beginning to the end) will be bolded in this way? Thanks,

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ `\AtBeginDocument{\pdfliteral direct{2 Tr 0.25 w}}`. If you see the code of the command, it's just code before `#1` and code after to revert the changes. Just put the code before wherever you want.

Comment: @ Manuel: I'm sorry to bother you again, but using your command, once my document exceed a page, the texts and formula in page 2, 3, ... are not bolded.

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Look at some package like `everypage` or `atbegshi`. With the latter, for instance, I think just doing `\AtBeginShipout{\pdfliteral direct{2 Tr 0.25 w}}` instead of `\AtBeginDocument` would be enough

Comment: @ Manuel: It is interesting that using \AtBeginShipout alone, everything except those in the first page is bolded.  Luckily I can fix this by using \AtBeginShipoutFirst simultaneously. Thanks for your help! Everything now looks great.

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ You may want to check the `\fontdimen`s. For instance, from the capture I uploaded, the bar of the fraction is the only thing that doesn't get thick.