# Colored "sum" in display math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, color

The line

```
\[ \textcolor{green}{\sum}_{k=0}^n \]
```

makes the `k=0` and `n` parts go to the right of Sigma instead of at the top and bottom, as it should be. Can we retain `k=0` and `n` at the top and bottom?

Comment: If you often use color in math-mode you may be interested in `\mathcolor` (avoids problems with spacing): [Colored symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85033)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `\textcolor` macro will undo the operator status of `\sum` so that both subscript and superscript are placed like they would at an ordinary symbol.

The macro `\mathop` makes the whole sequence (the green sum symbol) an operator again.

When you often use colored operator symbols, define a new macro, say

```
\newcommand*{\opcolor}[2]{\mathop{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}
```

and use it as `\opcolor{green}{\sum}`.

I have also defined a `\csum` macro based on `\opcolor`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\opcolor}[2]{\mathop{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\csum}[1]{\opcolor{#1}\sum}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathop{\textcolor{green}{\sum}}_{k=0}^n \]

\[ \csum{green}_{k=0}^n \]

\[ \opcolor{green}{\sum}_{k=0}^n \]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Isn’t \operatorname generally recommended over \mathop?

Comment: `\mathop` isn't a macro, it is TeX primitive.

Answer (score 8):

Declare the green symbol as an operator via `\mathop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathop{\textcolor{green}{\sum}}_{k=0}^n \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Color support in LaTeX is implemented by setting the color and resetting it after the end of the current group. `\textcolor` uses the curly braces as group. This has the side effect in math, that it also makes a subformula with horizontal spacing of a normal math atom.

The following example defines `\mathcolor` that uses `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` for the group without the side effect of a subformula in math.

If the integral is colored only, then the color reset inserts a special that prevents the proper working for the sub- and superscripts. `\mathop` helps for `\sum`, but will fail for `\int`, because TeX will no longer now, what's inside `\mathop{...}` if it sets the sub- and superscripts.

Therefore, the example uses green for the whole term including sub- and superscripts and sets black for the latter explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!80!black}% a littler darker

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mathcolor}{}
% Catch an optional argument in #1
\def\mathcolor#1#{\math@color{#1}}%
\newcommand*{\math@color}[3]{%
  % #1: empty or optional argument including brackets
  % #2: mandatory color argument
  % #3: stuff to be colored
  \begingroup\color#1{#2}#3\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathcolor{mygreen}{
    \int_{\mathcolor{black}{k=0}}^{\mathcolor{black}{n}}
  }
  \mathcolor{red}{=}
  \mathcolor{mygreen}{
    \int\limits_{\mathcolor{black}{k=0}}^{\mathcolor{black}{n}}
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Two questions: Why do you define `\mathcolor` twice? In the second definition, what is the effect of the second `#`? I can't make sense of the comments in your code.

Comment: @schtandard The first definition uses `\newcommand` that would throw an error message, if `\mathcolor` is already defined. `\def` does not do such checking. The `#` at the end of the parameter text catches right before a opening curly brace (the mandatory color argument here). Thus, `#1` gets all up to the `{`. Examples:  `\color[HTML]{FF0000}` with `#1` as `[HTML]`; `\color{mygreen}` with empty `#1`.

Answer (score 3):

With a recent version of LaTeX (2022-06-01) you can use `\mathcolor`: you just need to activate color support.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcolor{green!80!blue}{\sum}_{k=1}^n a_k
\]
\begin{center}
$\mathcolor{green!80!blue}{\sum}_{k=1}^n a_k$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The example shows that the colored operator works in all math styles.

[image]