# how do you color a percent (%) symbol?

Tags: symbols, color

im trying to color part of an expression with a percent symbol and its not working, the area  comes out blank after running latex, other stuff works, but anything containing a percent sign ends up messed up if i try to color it

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\title{\LaTeX}
\date{}
\begin{document}

This works:\\
{\color{red} (\mathrm{\\045 21})} \\
 this does not:
{\color{red} (\mathrm{\%o21})}


\end{document}
```

how do i do that?

Comment: actually, neither of them currently work- you need to enter into mathmode in some way, e.g `$....$` or `\[...\]`. Once you do that, everything works :)

Comment: Your example generates the error `! LaTeX Error: \mathrm allowed only in math mode.` which is unrelated to color. Do you mean your example to be in math mode, or did you intend to use `\textrm` ?

Comment: Related: [Colored symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85033) (for parts of math in color)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Remarks

You need to wrap all math related code in a math mode environment, i.e. either enclosing them in `$...$` or `\[...\]`.

## Implementation (Bad!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
This works:\\
{\color{red} ($\mathrm{\\045 21}$)} \\
 this does not:
{\color{red} ($\mathrm{\%o21}$)}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image: s]

## Much better

Using math mode and `\mathrm` only, where you need it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
This works: {\color{red} $(045 21)$}
This works, too: {\color{red} $(\%\mathrm{o}21)$}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image: s2]

Comment: One might ask *why* is math mode used in that code.

Comment: @egreg: You are right, of course. But according to the questions OP just wanted the color to work.

Comment: that was it. seems my latex is rusting