# Is it possible to change the color character by character in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, color

I know that it is possible to change the color of blocks of text, however I seem to be having trouble changing it character by character. I know it is possible to do it in LaTeX, but I'm not sure if it can be done in Lyx. I tried copying the code into the lyx 'LaTeX' box, but it spat out error messages. Any ideas?

Here is the thread that discusses how to change it in LaTeX:

[Colored symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85033/colored-symbols)

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that spat out error messages? What were the error messages? For more information, see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Is this what you had in mind?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Synesthesia.svg

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Mark the character you wish to color, the go to `Edit > Text Style > Customized` and choose the color you wish your character to have. Repeat for the next character.

[image]

You can speed this process up by adding a shortcut to the dialog box: `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts > New`, then as function use `dialog-show character`.