# Is it possible to set the color of partial text inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes

I have a tikz `node \node[] {blah};`

and I want to set the color of half the text, such as "ah" to a different color without having to create a new node and try to make everything stick together through positioning. (My text is more complicated, it involves formulas where I want to color some things in it to specify additional information).

Comment: As you mention that you have formulas, you may also want to have a look at `\mathcolor` from [Colored symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85035/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the color inside the node's text with `\textcolor` (thanks to TeXnician):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=red]{bl\textcolor{blue}{ah}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\textcolor`? `\color` works on the group and doesn't take a second argument.

Comment: @TeXnician Ups! Yes, you're right. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have tried it... It works in math. Seems one should use mathcolor though @Peter Grill