# Using a character as a macro within another macro in (La)TeX

Tags: math-mode, macros

Goal: What I would like to do is to allow `_` and `^` to be used to generate sub and superscripts in text mode only within a specific macro. I know that I can make `_` and `^` active throughout the document, but that messes with other packages which assume that they will not be.

I've dug around a bit, and haven't found an example that implements something close to what I want.

I've been basing my code off of examples like https://texfaq.org/FAQ-actinarg This works for creating a command in which the argument is typeset with `_` and `^` being active:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active%
\gdef_#1{\ensuremath{{}\sb{#1}}}%
\catcode`^=\active%
\gdef^#1{\ensuremath{{}\sp{#1}}}%
\endgroup

\def\subsup{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`_=\active
    \catcode`^=\active
    \Xsubsup
}
\def\Xsubsup#1{%
    #1%
  \endgroup
}

\subsup{foo_x bar^y baz}

% foo_a bar^b baz % this will cause an error because _ is not active.
```

Now, if I add the function that I want to embed this in:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\newMacro[2][\null]{
  % other processing and formatting not directly relevant to this example
  \subsup{#2}%
}

\newMacro{foo_x bar^y baz}
\end{document}
```

I get math mode errors:

```
ERROR: Missing $ inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                $
l.28 \newMacro{foo_x bar^y baz}
```

So I tried to embed the subsup macros into `newMacro` (I've repeated some of the code from above for ease of copying and pasting.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active%
\gdef_#1{\ensuremath{{}\sb{#1}}}%
\catcode`^=\active%
\gdef^#1{\ensuremath{{}\sp{#1}}}%
\endgroup

\DeclareRobustCommand*\newMacro[2][\null]{
\def\subsup{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`_=\active
    \catcode`^=\active
    \Xsubsup
}
\def\Xsubsup#1{%
    #1%
  \endgroup
}
  % other processing and formatting not directly relevant to this example
  \subsup{#2}%
}

\subsup{foo_x bar^y baz} %this is undefined, and so fails because newMacro hasn't been called yet.

\newMacro{foo_x bar^y baz}

\subsup{foo_x bar^y baz} % this works because it comes after newMacro has been called.
\end{document}
```

This still doesn't work, but now I get the error:

```
ERROR: Use of \Xsubsup doesn't match its definition.

--- TeX said ---
\\newMacro  ...\Xsubsup #1{#1\endgroup } \subsup {
                                                  #2}
l.28 \newMacro{foo_x bar^y baz}
```

Why do the two `subsup` functions work only when not embedded in another macro? Why do I get errors that `Xsubsup` doesn't match its definition only when it is embedded within another macro? Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: When an argument is absorbed, category codes are fixed, so `\supsub` or other macros cannot change them.

Comment: Is 'search and replace' possible? For example, `\foo{bar_{baz}}` is doable but something like `\foo{{baz_{bar}}}` is much more tricky.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer is that it is not possible.

This is exactly why you can not use `\verb` in the argument of another macro. catcode assignments *only* affect the conversion of unparsed characters in the input file into character tokens. Once you pass token lists around as `#1` etc you are passing lists of tokens and each token has a catcode already so the catcode assignments are not looked at.

so when you have

```
\subsup{#2}%
```

It is passed as token list that has already been constructed so although the catcodes of `_` are changed it doesn't matter tex is not going to see an unparsed `_` character only a `_` token that already has its normal catcode.

However if you are prepared to be very modern and use an e-Tex extension from the 1990's then you can re-tokenize a tokenlist using the `\scantokens` primitive. `\scantokens` essentially writes its arguments out to an internal file stream and then reads it back as if from `\input` using the catcodes in effect so changing

```
\def\Xsubsup#1{%
    #1%
  \endgroup
```

to

```
\def\Xsubsup##1{%
   \scantokens{##1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Fixes things, The meet its definition error is because you had use `#1` rather than `##1` in the inner definition.

Comment: This works excellently! Thanks for the incredibly quick response.

Comment: (several years later) now expl3 has regex_replace_all, but still the same thing can be implemented in plain TeX. With limitations.

Comment: @user202729 I'm only using plain tex (actually tex primitives) plus e-tex here, so I don't understand your comment. expl3 requires etex+pdftex primitoves so does not work with theformat used with `tex` in texlive.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to David's answer, you could try having `\newMacro` take fewer arguments and let the final call to `\subsup` absorb what would be the second argument.  Here's my suggested code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\newMacro[1][\null]{
  \let\subsup\@subsup
  % Other stuff
  \subsup
}

\def\@subsup#{
  \bgroup
  \catcode`^=\active
  \catcode`_=\active
  \let\next=
}
\makeatother

\begingroup
\catcode`^=\active
\catcode`_=\active
\gdef^#1{\ensuremath{{}\sp{#1}}}
\gdef_#1{\ensuremath{{}\sb{#1}}}
\endgroup

\newMacro{ab_c}

\end{document}
```

I like the [`#{` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13436/575) in delimited macros.  It enforces the use of braces in the argument to be passed to `\subsup` and, simultaneously, uses the braces to form a group that protects the catcode change.

This of course only works if the *last* thing that `\newMacro` does is call `\subsup`.  However, even if it wants to do other stuff, in the manner of

```
\newcommand\newMacro[1]{
  % stuff
  \subsup{#1}
  % more stuff
}
```

you can simply break it into several macros, in much the same way that your original definition of `\subsup` was broken, with the help of the somewhat-obscure `\aftergroup` directive:

```
% #1 is a token to put after \subsup
\def\subsup#1#{
  \bgroup
  % catcode changes
  \aftergroup#1
  \let\next=
}
\def\newMacro{
  % stuff
  \subsup{\XnewMacro}
}
\def\XnewMacro{
  % more stuff
}
```

And in this way you can completely skip over the "argument" in which the catcode changes are to occur.