# How can I use the same parameter for \Tree and \exi

Tags: macros, linguistics, qtree, linguex

The `qtree` package permits drawing syntactic trees with a syntax like this:

```
\ex. \Tree [.S [.NP This ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP an example ]]]
```

The `linguex` package typesets bracketed expressions with a similar syntax:

```
\exi. [S [NP This ] [VP [V is ] [NP an example. ]]]
```

As you see, the only difference is that the labels in `\Tree` command (S, NP, VP etc.) are preceded by a dot. 
Now, I want to write a macro which gets such an argument and first produces a bracketed expression with `\exi.` and then a tree with `\Tree`. In order to achieve this I tried to define the following macro, which would add dots after the [ bracket:

```
\newcommand{\dotify}[1]{\catcode`[=13 \def[{\[.} {#1} \catcode`[=12}
```

This doesn't work, however. Could anyone help me out with this? Or maybe there is a simpler way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New answer**: You want to do an "input substitution", as compared with an "output substitution".  That is, you want to replace `[` with `[.` as material in the .tex file, rather than as printable material.  More precisely, you don't want to have the braces replace themselves "as you go along", because the `\Tree` command will absorb them all at once and not allow them to be executed before it parses what's written, which will not have the dots yet inserted.

In short, what you want is to do a string substitution replacing `[` with `[.`, saving the result in a macro that can then be expanded after `\Tree` to give it the correct syntax.  For this, the `stringstrings` package seems ideal.  Here's a minimal document showing how you can define a macro to automate the whole process for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings,qtree,linguex}
\newcommand*\dotify[1]{%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{[}{[.}%
}
\newcommand*\doboth[1]{%
  \dotify{#1}%
  \ex. \expandafter\Tree\thestring

  \exi. #1

}
\begin{document}
\doboth{[S [NP This ] [VP [V is ] [NP an example ]]]}
\end{document}
```

**Old answer:** If you do want to do something like this with catcode methods, you still have a few problems.  Most critically, you can't make catcode changes to a macro argument that has already been read, so you should *not* declare `\dotify` as having an argument.  Instead, you should use the braces delimiting its "argument" to contain a group that "sets up" the correct parsing context; see [this interesting answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13436/575) for the source (for me) of this trick.  The group will naturally restrict the scope of the catcode change as well; a bonus.

Your other problem is that `\[` means `\begin{equation}` and not a left brace.  I'm sure there's already a command for that, but you can define your own with `\let\lb[`.

With these changes, the correct code would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\activebrace{\catcode`\[=\active}
\let\lb[
{\activebrace \global\def[{\lb.}}
\def\dotify#{%
  \bgroup
    \activebrace
    \let\next=%
}
\begin{document}
\dotify{[a[b[c]]]}
\end{document}
```

which outputs `[.a[.b[.c]]]`.

Comment: But what Ariel wants is to be able to pass the output of dotify as the argument of the `\Tree` command, so that `\Tree \dotify{[a [b [c ]]]}` will be typeset exactly as `\Tree [.a [.b [.c ]]]` would be.

Comment: @AlanMunn That's not possible no matter how `\dotify` is defined, unless `\Tree` expands its argument, and even then, it can't work unless `\dotify` is fully expandable (which it's not, if it makes a `\catcode` change.

Comment: Thanks for the new answer.  I wasn't aware of the `stringstrings` package.  That's a pretty neat trick.

Comment: The author is on this site, too.  I learn about all kinds of neat packages here (tikz being the big one).

Comment: Thanks. This looks reasonably simple, but how do I combine it then into a macro which will do both the `\exi.` and the `\Tree` on the same parameter?

Comment: @Ariel: how about my new example?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `\doubletree` macro with `l3regex`. I show both inputs for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree,linguex,xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doubletree}{m}
 {
  \ariel_do_double_tree:n { #1 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__ariel_tree_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ariel_do_double_tree:n #1
 {
  %% print the first representation
  \exi.~#1\par

  %% change it for \Tree
  \tl_set:Nn \l__ariel_tree_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \[ } { \[\. } \l__ariel_tree_tl
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l__ariel_tree_tl { \Tree }
  \tl_use:N \l__ariel_tree_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\exi. [S [NP This ] [VP [V is ] [NP an example. ]]]

\Tree [.S [.NP This ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP an example ]]]

\bigskip

\doubletree{[S [NP This ] [VP [V is ] [NP an example. ]]] }

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here's a (less efficient) version without `l3regex`, with identical output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree,linguex,xstring}

\newcommand{\doubletree}[1]{%
  \exi. #1\par
  \saveexpandmode
  \noexpandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{[}{[.}[\temp]
  \expandafter\Tree\temp
  \restoreexpandmode}

\begin{document}
\exi. [S [NP This ] [VP [V is ] [NP an example. ]]]

\Tree [.S [.NP This ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP an example ]]]

\bigskip

\doubletree{[S [NP This ] [VP [V is ] [NP an example. ]]] }

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I need to learn LaTeX3.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the `l3regex' package in my package list.

Comment: @Ariel Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: @Ariel I've added a "l3regex-free" version

Comment: @egreg Thanks, this works for me! It seems it is essentially the same idea as in the answer above, but with the `xstring` package, instead of `stringstrings`. So which package is better?

Comment: @Ariel The `xstring` solution doesn't require any juggling of category codes.

Comment: @egreg As far as I can see both solutions don't require any catcode changes, but I'm unaware of the underlying mechanism.