# How can I write <section counter value>:<section title>:<page>:<file>:<line> to the log whenever (and whereever) a macro is called?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, expansion, patching

I am working on *context-based* log entries. Each time a *selected (patched) macro* is called, it should provide its contents along with a meaningful log entry.

## "Meaningful" log entry defined:

The following context is given per custom log entry:

- section counter value
- section title
- page number
- file name/path
- line number

**This is what I want**:

```
<macro content> (<section counter value>:<section title>:<page number>:<file>:<line number>)
```

## Problems

I have two problems I guess:

1. Dealing with `\thetitle` when one of these selected macros falls within a sectioning command itself.
2. Getting full value of expanded macro into log as string in case with `\myproduct` macro.

## How I have implemented "meaningful" log entries

- `\thetitle` **get section counter** `titlesec`
- `\@currentlabelname` **get section title** `titlesec` provides `\def\@currentlabelname` for nameref  (I only tested this with straight classes, that is, classes with nobottomtitles)
- `\thepage` **get page** LaTeX
- `\the\inputlineno` **get line number** LaTeX (refers to lineno in current file when using `\input`)
- *`max_print_line=10000` in `texmf.cnf` to expand max chars per line in log output (irrelevant to this question, but relevant for people who might also want to implement custom logs)*

Hopefully I have my facts straight above.

## Problem 2 (almost working, typesets fine)

Sometimes my section titles contains macros. This could lead to expansion problems. Also, sometimes the section titles contain the very macro I am tracking, which makes it tricky to use `\thetitle` in the log entry e.g. `\section{About \myproduct{monkey shampoo}}` which should yield e.g. `MacGyver.monkey shampoo (2:About MacGyver.monkey shampoo:[1]:test.tex:11)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% use xelatex
\usepackage{titlesec}% adds \thetitle and \@currentlabelname
\usepackage{currfile}% adds \currfilepath

% Define a couple commands to track
\newcommand\myapp[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\myproduct[1]{MacGyver.\textit{#1}}% Purposefully made this one contain more text that what is saved in #1

% The following is normally put into separate file as to modularize the application of patches
% Define a context macro as described
\makeatletter
\def\contextinfo{\thetitle:\@currentlabelname:[\thepage]:\currfilepath:\the\inputlineno}
\makeatother
% Apply Patches
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\xapptocmd{\myapp}{\typeout{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\myproduct}{\typeout{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}}{}{}% <-- I'd rather show MacGyver.monkey shampoo, but unsure how best to implement
% Note: \typeout is always fully expanded due to \write %http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60976/13552

\begin{document}
\section{Elephant}
\section{Monkey}
\subsection{Bonabo}
\myapp{listmonkeys}
\myproduct{monkey shampoo}
\end{document}
```

### Log Output

See problem 2 above: How can I make "**monkey shampoo**" be "**MacGyver.monkey shampoo**" or maybe easier: **MacGyver.\textit{monkey shampoo}**

```
 ==> listmonkeys (2.1:Bonabo:[1]:test.tex:34)
 ==> monkey shampoo (2.1:Bonabo:[1]:test.tex:35)
```

## Problem 1 (not working, does not typeset)

See Problem 1 above: How can I deal with the `\thetitle`, which is defined in `titlesec` by `\gdef\thetitle{\csname the#1\endcsname}%`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% use xelatex
\usepackage{titlesec}% adds \thetitle and \@currentlabelname
\usepackage{currfile}% adds \currfilepath

% Define a couple commands to track
\newcommand\myapp[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\myproduct[1]{MacGyver.\textit{#1}}% Purposefully made this one contain more text that what is saved in #1

% The following is normally put into separate file as to modularize the application of patches
% Define a context macro as described
\makeatletter
\def\contextinfo{\thetitle:\@currentlabelname:[\thepage]:\currfilepath:\the\inputlineno}
\makeatother
% Apply Patches
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\xapptocmd{\myapp}{\typeout{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\myproduct}{\typeout{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}}{}{}% <-- I'd rather show MacGyver.monkey shampoo, but unsure how best to implement
% Note: \typeout is always fully expanded due to \write %http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60976/13552

\begin{document}
\section{Elephant \myapp{watcher}}% probably \thetitle has not been set yet, causing error
\section{Monkey \myproduct{monkey shampoo}}
\subsection{Bonabo}
\end{document}
```

### Log Output

`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`

Comment: The first thing to try is \tracingmacros=1and \tracingmacros=2

Comment: @JohnKormylo I like how the first response I get is from a guy whose profile states "I am unemployable/retired and get bored." haha. cracking me up.

Comment: My other hobby is http://www.elfsoft2000.com/chess/index.htm

Comment: I think, it's `\@currentlabelname` that causes the stuff to fail somehow

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, well that could be. I was not sure of `\thetitle`. They are both defined under `\def\ttl@straight@i#1[#2]%` in `titlesec.sty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big issue you have to deal with is expandability of content, since you're writing to the terminal. To get around this, I define two versions of your `\myapp` and `\myproduct` functions. The regular `\myapp` and `\myproduct` are declared to be robust, while `\@myapp` and `\@myproduct` are expandable and simplified versions of their counterparts (removing font-related settings like `\textit`, for example).

I also avoided the complexities of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and construct my own `\thenumber` (that contains the section number) and `\thetitle` (that contains the section title using the simplified versions of `\@myapp` and/or `\@myproduct`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile}% adds \currfilepath

% Define a couple commands to track
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myapp}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myproduct}[1]{MacGyver.\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@myapp}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\@myproduct}[1]{MacGyver.#1}
\makeatother

% The following is normally put into separate file as to modularize the application of patches
% Define a context macro as described
\def\contextinfo{\thenumber:\thetitle:[\thepage]:\currfilepath:\the\inputlineno}

% Apply Patches
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\xapptocmd{\myapp}{\typeout{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\myproduct}{\typeout{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}}{}{}% <-- I'd rather show MacGyver.monkey shampoo, but unsure how best to implement
% Note: \typeout is always fully expanded due to \write %http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60976/13552

%\usepackage{xparse}% Loaded by regexpatch
\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \begingroup
  % Extract the counter representation
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \xdef\thenumber{\thesection}%
  \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  % Temporarily change \myapp and \myproduct to be expandable and ordinary
  \let\myapp\@myapp
  \let\myproduct\@myproduct
  % Extract the title with possible \myapp and \myproduct (now ordinary/expandable)
  \protected@xdef\thetitle{#3}%
  \endgroup
  % Regular section
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsection{#3}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Elephant \myapp{watcher}}% probably \thetitle has not been set yet, causing error
\section{About \myproduct{monkey shampoo}}
\subsection{Bonabo}

\end{document}
```

The `.log` outputs

```
 ==> watcher (1:Elephant watcher:[1]:test.tex:48)
 ==> monkey shampoo (2:About MacGyver.monkey shampoo:[1]:test.tex:49)
```

Comment: If I wanted to wrap `\contextinfo` in `\AtEndAfterFileList`, how would I expand the internal macros once beforehand to ensure that the context is correct. (I am applying your ingenious code to subsection and so forth.) Maybe this warrants an entirely new question, however. Like "add to macro the expanded context" and typeset that \AtEndAfterFileList" is what I was thinking.

Comment: I opened a new question for this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318400/how-can-i-pass-expanded-material-to-a-macro-at-definition-time-context-specific

Comment: @Werner; Is it possible to convert the normal para also a separate file? Please advise...If you need more information, I'll provide...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% use xelatex
\usepackage{titlesec}% adds \thetitle and \@currentlabelname
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage{currfile}% adds \currfilepath


% Define a couple commands to track
\newcommand\myapp[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\myproduct[1]{MacGyver.\textit{#1}}% Purposefully made this one contain more text that what is saved in #1

% The following is normally put into separate file as to modularize the application of patches
% Define a context macro as described

\makeatletter
\def\contextinfo{\thetitle\space:\@currentlabelname:[\thepage]:\currfilepath:\the\inputlineno}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\WriteToLog}[1]{%
  \gdef\@currentlabelname{#1}\immediate\write-1{ ==> #1 (\contextinfo)}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\xapptocmd{\myapp}{\WriteToLog{#1}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\myproduct}{\WriteToLog{#1}}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Elephant \myapp{watcher}}\label{foo}% probably \thetitle has not been set yet, causing error
\section{Monkey \myproduct{monkey shampoo}}
\subsection{Bonabo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you got it to compile! Not quite there, because this does yet solve the section title issue when a macro is in the title itself (the `\@currentlabelname` only contains macro contents, not section title).

Comment: @macmadness86: Well, your `goal` is a little bit confusing for me and I doubt it's the best strategy

Comment: You're right about that. I think I am going to need the aux file. I might need to make a list of macros that expand on the second run. Otherwise, I am not sure how I can deal with this situation: `\section{About \myproduct{monkey shampoo}}` such that my log shows e.g.: `==> MacGyver.monkey shampoo (2:About MacGyver.monkey shampoo:[1]:test.tex:11)`

Comment: Is it possible to convert the normal para also a separate file? Please advise...If you need more information, I'll provide...

Answer (score 1):

## "Macro Tracker" Solution  *update 2016-07-12*

Based on Werner's  code, I came up with a nice logging solution.

On the journey to producing a clean log output:

```
##############################################################################
  Document Diagnostics
##############################################################################
Main File: logs.tex
Page Count: 2


 xparsemacro
##############################################################################
--BEGIN-----------------------------------------------------------------------
==> pre-section example (::logs.tex:[1]:144)
==> post-section example (1:Section:logs.tex:[1]:147)
==> post-section example (1.1:Subsection:logs.tex:[1]:150)
==> post-section example (1.1.1:Subsubsection:logs.tex:[1]:153)
==> post-section example (1.1.1.1:Paragraph:logs.tex:[1]:156)
==> in-section call (2:\xparsemacro {in-section call}:logs.tex:[1]:159)
--END-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code works best for simple, single,-input macros used as tags that might be scattered throughout your text. Also, the log looks nicer with the environment variable `max_print_line` set to some higher number than 79. e.g. `export max_print_line=1000` In my `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` file, I commented out

> ```
> 770 %error_line = 79
> 771 %half_error_line = 50
> 772 %max_print_line = 79
> ```

and added them to `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf.cnf`

> ```
>  11 error_line = 254
>  12 half_error_line = 238
>  13 max_print_line = 1000
> ```

### How to use

1. Define single-input (`#1`) macros with `xparse's` `\NewDocumentCommand`  (Note that using `\newcommand` can cause recursive calls when they contain formatting macros like `\texttt`)
2. Add macro to list of tracked macros `\doforeach{}` without slash

## Experimental Code

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % define \do
\usepackage{atveryend} % define \AtEndAfterFileList
\usepackage{currfile} % define \currfilepath
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% My Macros (Variable Placeholders)
%
\newcommand\latexmacro[1]{#1}
\newcommand\latexmacrott[1]{\texttt{latex}.#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\latexrobusttt}[1]{\texttt{latexrobust}.#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparsemacro}{m}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparsemacrott}{m}{\texttt{xparse}.#1}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Log Delimiters
%
\catcode`#=12 % Define out log output delimiter lines using # as catcode 12 instead of 6
  \newcommand{\macloglineL}{##############################################################################}
  \newcommand{\macloglineB}{--BEGIN-----------------------------------------------------------------------}
  \newcommand{\macloglineE}{--END-------------------------------------------------------------------------}
\catcode`#=6
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Initialize Variables and Define Context-specific log entry
%
\def\currnum{}% initialize (for when section not yet typeset)
\def\currtitle{}% initialize (for when section not yet typeset)
\def\contextinfo{\currnum:\currtitle:\currfilepath:[\thepage]:\the\inputlineno}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Create loop macro that supports macros as items
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\doforeach[2]{\renewcommand\do[1]{#2}\docsvlist{#1}}% Needs etoolbox http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318875/how-can-i-loop-through-macros-with-foreach-and-pass-them-to-xapptocmd 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Make Document Diagnostics Header
%
\def\docdiagnosticsheader{%
\typeout{%
\macloglineL
^^J%
\space\space Document Diagnostics
^^J%
\macloglineL%
^^J%
Main File: \jobname.tex
^^J%
Page Count: \thepage
}
}%
\AtEndAfterFileList{\docdiagnosticsheader}
% Patch loop (syntax: \doforeach{macro,macro,macro}{what to do for each item})
% Patches tag macros
%
\doforeach{latexmacro,latexmacrott,latexrebusttt,xparsemacro,xparsemacrott}{% macro names wmacout slashes
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1-tracker\endcsname\relax
    % does not exist, so create it
    \expandafter\def\csname #1-tracker\endcsname{^^J^^J #1 ^^J\macloglineL^^J\macloglineB}
  \else
    % exists, do nothing
  \fi
  \expandafter\xapptocmd\csname#1\endcsname{\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname #1-tracker\endcsname{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname #1-tracker\endcsname}^^J==> \unexpanded{##1}           (\contextinfo)}}{\typeout{MACMessage: Successfully patched #1}}{\typeout{MACWarning: Failed to patch #1}}% 2 \expandafter needed, yet 3 are here because one is just to prep the \csname token.
\AtEndAfterFileList{\expandafter\typeout{\csname #1-tracker\endcsname^^J\macloglineE}}% Uncomment to enable tracking in log output
}%
\makeatother


% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The following temporarily redefine sectioning commands to extract titleno and title as \currnum and \currtitle, respectively for \contextinfo
%
\let\oldsection\section%  Redefine section to grab number + title when tracking macros
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \begingroup
  \stepcounter{section}% Extract the counter representation
  \xdef\currnum{\thesection}%
  \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \protected@xdef\currtitle{#3}% Extract the title wmac possible tracked macros
  \endgroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Regular section
    {\oldsection*{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsection{#3}}}
}
\makeatother

\let\oldsubsection\subsection%  Redefine section to grab number + title when tracking macros
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s o m}{%
  \begingroup
  \stepcounter{subsection}% Extract the counter representation
  \xdef\currnum{\thesubsection}%
  \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}% Restore for normal subsection
  \protected@xdef\currtitle{#3}% Extract the title wmac possible tracked macros
  \endgroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Regular section
    {\oldsubsection*{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsubsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsubsection{#3}}}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{s o m}{%
  \begingroup
  \stepcounter{subsubsection}% Extract the counter representation
  \xdef\currnum{\thesubsubsection}%
  \addtocounter{subsubsection}{-1}% Restore for normal subsection
  \protected@xdef\currtitle{#3}% Extract the title wmac possible tracked macros
  \endgroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Regular section
    {\oldsubsubsection*{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsubsubsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsubsubsection{#3}}}
}
\makeatother

\let\oldparagraph\paragraph%  Redefine section to grab number + title when tracking macros
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\paragraph}{s o m}{%
  \begingroup
  \stepcounter{paragraph}% Extract the counter representation
  \xdef\currnum{\theparagraph}%
  \addtocounter{paragraph}{-1}% Restore for normal subsection
  \protected@xdef\currtitle{#3}% Extract the title wmac possible tracked macros
  \endgroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Regular section
    {\oldparagraph*{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldparagraph[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldparagraph{#3}}}
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\latexmacro{pre-section example}
\xparsemacro{pre-section example}
\section{Section}
\latexmacro{post-section example}
\xparsemacro{post-section example}
\subsection{Subsection}
\latexmacro{post-section example}
\xparsemacro{post-section example}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\latexmacro{post-section example}
\xparsemacro{post-section example}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\latexmacro{post-section example}
\xparsemacro{post-section example}
%\section{\latexmacrott{in-section call}}
%\section{\latexrebusttt{in-section call}}
\section{\xparsemacro{in-section call}}
\section{\xparsemacrott{in-section call}}
%\subsection{\latexmacro{in-subsection call}\xparsemacro{in-subsection call}}
%\subsubsection{\latexmacro{in-subsubsection call}\xparsemacro{in-subsubsection call}}
%\paragraph{\latexmacro{in-paragraph call}\xparsemacro{in-paragraph call}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert the normal para also a separate file? Please advise...If you need more information, I'll provide...

Comment: @MadyYuvi It would be better to open a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, already raised and the link is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594941/converting-latex-tags-by-equivalent-html-tags-using-own-tags/594988?noredirect=1#comment1492467_594988