# How can I loop through macros with \foreach and pass them to \xapptocmd?

Tags: macros, pgf-core, patching

Can I use `pgffor` to loop through macros (control sequences)? e.g. `\foreach \macro in {\lions,\tigers,\bears}`

In case you haven't figured it out, **I love modularization**!

Let's say I have three commands to patch:

1. `\a1`
2. `\a2`
3. `\a3`

## Pseudo-Code

This code was an attempt to achieve what I want. For fun and to test my understanding, I used `\csname` to create macros with numbers in their names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a1\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a2\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a3\endcsname[1]{}

\foreach \macro in {\csname a1\endcsname,\csname a2\endcsname,\csname a3\endcsname} {%
  \expandafter\xapptocmd{\macro}{\unexpanded{#1}, oh my!}{}{}% Apply patches to all macros in list
}%
\begin{document}
\csname a1\endcsname{Lions}

\csname a2\endcsname{tigers}

\csname a3\endcsname{and bears}
\end{document}
```

## Expected Page Output

```
Lions, oh my!

tigers, oh my!

and bears, on my!
```

---

## Alternative semi-working Example without `\csname`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\newcommand\lions[1]{}
\newcommand\tigers[1]{}
\newcommand\bears[1]{}

%\foreach \macro in {\lions,\tigers,\bears} {% Loop up the following junk
  \xapptocmd{\lions}{\unexpanded{#1}, oh my!}{}{}% inefficient use of my time
  \xapptocmd{\tigers}{\unexpanded{#1}, oh my!}{}{}% inefficient use of my time
  \xapptocmd{\bears}{\unexpanded{#1}, oh my!}{}{}% inefficient use of my time
%}%
\begin{document}
\lions{Lions}

\tigers{tigers}

\bears{and bears}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: The usage of  numbers in a command name is not really recommendable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Understood, but what about this? I find it quite useful to have dynamic generation of macros https://www.tug.org/tug2012/booklet/hendrickson/AmyTugProc.pdf

Comment: Well, you have to use `\csname ....\endcsname` each time you want to use it

Comment: If you want to use your `\foreach` loop, you have to use `##1` instead of `#1`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Where'd your answer go? I was about to accept it! I think it would be quite beneficial for the community to offer as many alternatives as possible!

Comment: I've deleted it. Actually, your questions tend to be very unclear and change the question from x to y in many occasions. Accept one of the other questions

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This question is pretty clear I think.  I know not to change questions after answers have been given, and to objectively accept an answer that has effectively answered the question even if it doesn't solve my real-world problem. I would have accepted your answer. It *did* answer the question (with your `foreach` update) and provided a useful `expl3` alternative. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, apart from using `expl3` loops (like `\clist_map_inline:nn`), the provided by `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox,regexpatch}

\csdef{a1}#1{}
\csdef{a2}#1{}
\csdef{a3}#1{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\do[1]{\expandafter\xapptocmd\csname#1\endcsname{##1, oh my!}{}{\typeout{Misreable filure}}}
\docsvlist{a1,a2,a3}

\csuse{a1}{Lions}\par
\csuse{a2}{tigers}\par
\csuse{a3}{and bears}

\end{document}
```

I used `\csdef` and `\csuse` just to show them, you can use `\expandafter\newcommand\csname .. \endcsname` and `\csname .. \endcsname`, like always.

As egreg says, the always repeating problem with `\foreach` is the fact that everything is inside a group. I've never thought about it, but I don't know why isn't it defined something like `\foreach \foo in { a, b } { <code> }` to be `\let\save\foo \def\foo{a} <code> \def\foo{b} <code> \let\foo\save`, which would solve many things. In any case, if you want to define yourself a complete macro that will automate everything you can do, for example, this two options:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\doforeach[2]{\renewcommand\do[1]{#2}\docsvlist{#1}}
```

or

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \doforeach { +m +m } { \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and then you can use easily

```
\doforeach{a1,a2,a3}{\expandafter\xapptocmd\csname#1\endcsname{##1, oh my!}{}{\typeout{Misreable filure}}}
```

and you don't have to type difficult things.

Comment: Thanks! That is a pretty cool alternative. I am not sure which answer to accept because they all make useful contributions :)

Comment: `Misreable filure` indeed ;)

Comment: Answering to your question to Christian, if you want `\protected@xdef` inside expl3 code you can use it like `\use:c { protected@xdef }`.

Answer (score 2):

The usual problem: `\foreach` does its job in a group, so the patch is nullified as soon as the group ends. However, you're trying to patch `\macro`, which expands to `\csname a1\endcsname` and so on, so the attempt is obviously unsuccessful.

Define `\temp` to be the same as a “double expansion” of `\macro`; patch it; globally redefine the `\csname` macro to the patched version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a1\endcsname[1]{#1}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a2\endcsname[1]{#1}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a3\endcsname[1]{#1}

\foreach \macro in {\csname a1\endcsname,\csname a2\endcsname,\csname a3\endcsname}
  {%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp\macro
   \xapptocmd\temp{, oh my!}{}{}%
   \global\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\macro\temp
  }

\begin{document}
\csname a1\endcsname{Lions}

\csname a2\endcsname{tigers}

\csname a3\endcsname{and bears}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how you can do if you want the argument specifier in the patch. Note the doubling of `#`, because we're in the argument to `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a1\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a2\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a3\endcsname[1]{}

\foreach \macro in {\csname a1\endcsname,\csname a2\endcsname,\csname a3\endcsname}
  {%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp\macro
   \xapptocmd\temp{##1, oh my!}{}{}%
   \global\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\macro\temp
  }

\begin{document}
\csname a1\endcsname{Lions}

\csname a2\endcsname{tigers}

\csname a3\endcsname{and bears}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining things. By the way, `#1`was put intentionally in the patch. In a real-world situation, my patch would be e.g. `\typeout{==> #1 (2.2:Subsection Title:filepath:[pageno]:lineno)}` (custom modularized/hot-swappable logging package)

Comment: @macmadness86 I added the version with `#1` in the patch

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `\seq` list and expand it inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname macro1\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname macro2\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname macro3\endcsname[1]{}



\begin{document}
Before patching:

\csname macro1\endcsname{Lions}
\csname macro2\endcsname{Tigers}
\csname macro3\endcsname{and Bears}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {macro1,macro2,macro3}
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq  {%
 \exp_after:wN \xapptocmd\cs:w #1\cs_end:{##1,~oh~my!}{\typeout{Success!}}{}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

After patching:

\csname macro1\endcsname{Lions}

\csname macro2\endcsname{Tigers}

\csname macro3\endcsname{and Bears}


\end{document}
```

Other version, using the correct parameter `##1` and and a by-pass with `\global\csletcs`, since `\foreach` runs it's code a group only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a1\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a2\endcsname[1]{}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname a3\endcsname[1]{}

\begin{document}

\foreach \macro in {a1,a2,a3} {%
  \let\santaslittlehelper\macro
  \expandafter\xapptocmd\csname \santaslittlehelper\endcsname{##1, oh my!}{}{\typeout{Miserable failure}}% Apply patches to all macros in list
  \global\csletcs{\macro}{\santaslittlehelper}
}
\csname a1\endcsname{Lions}

\csname a2\endcsname{tigers}

\csname a3\endcsname{and bears}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I was hoping to avoid LaTeX3 syntax. Why did you switch `\xappcmd`  to `\xpatchcmd`?

Comment: @macmadness86: Call it a typo ;-)

Comment: @macmadness86: Look on the `expl3`-less version (which is not true, since `regexpatch` is a `expl3` package ;-)

Comment: "`\santaslittlehelper`" haha. Do you know how to put `\protected@xdef` into the exp3 version? I am not sure where to put the `\protected@xdef` because of aux.

Comment: @macmadness86: There's **no** `.aux` issue in your question

Comment: True. I thought I was a pro and could identify and wrap the appropriate scopes with`\makeatletter \makeatother` to get `\protected@xdef` to work, so I didn't complicate the question by using it.

Comment: @macmadness86: But you're changing the question again :-(