# converting LaTeX tags by equivalent HTML tags using own tags

Tags: conversion, html

I am writing some small conversion script from the TeX application file, and the `MWE` is:

```
\newwrite\html
\immediate\openout\html\jobname.html

\newcommand{\HalfTitle}[1]{\thispagestyle{empty}\bgroup%
\vbox to \vsize{\vfill%
\hbox to \hsize{\hss\Large#1\hss}%
\vfill}%
\immediate\write\html{<TPHT>#1</TPHT>}%
\egroup\clearemptydoublepage}%
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\html}

\HalfTitle{Half Title}
```

Output `filename.html` created as:

```
<TPHT>Half Title</TPHT>
```

By using the same method, I want to get the some group of text within the tag `<copyrt>...</copyrt>`, i.e.,

```
\begin{copyrt}
\textcopyright\ Copyright text goes here

lines
\end{copyrt}
```

Output should be:

```
<copyrt>
<p>\textcopyright\ Copyright text goes here</p>

<p>lines</p>
</copyrt>
```

Please advise....

Comment: There's a package that collects the body of a specified environment (like `environ` does) and then you can output it etc, but I can't recall the name.

Comment: Could be `newenviron` package.

Comment: @Cicada: you probably meant `environ` https://ctan.org/pkg/environ?lang=en (yes, there is also a separate `newenviron` package, but the former is better documented IMHO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xparse` (which is built into LaTeX since the 2020-10-01 release) with the `b` argument that grabs the environment body, then you can use `\seq_set_split:Nnn` to split the body of the environment at each `\par` and write that to the `.html` file.  Careful that with this definition you cannot use verbatim-like commands and environments in your `copyrt` environment.

Running the example below produces this `.html` file:

```html
<TPHT>Half Title</TPHT>
<copyrt>
<p>\textcopyright \ Copyright text goes here</p>
<p>lines</p>
</copyrt>
```

```latex
\newwrite\html
\immediate\openout\html\jobname.html

\newcommand{\HalfTitle}[1]{\thispagestyle{empty}\bgroup%
\vbox to \vsize{\vfill%
\hbox to \hsize{\hss\Large#1\hss}%
\vfill}%
\immediate\write\html{<TPHT>#1</TPHT>}%
\egroup
% \clearemptydoublepage % <-- Don't know where this is from so I used
  \cleardoublepage % instead
}%
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\html}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__madyyuvi_paragraphs_seq
\NewDocumentEnvironment{copyrt}{+b}
  {
    \iow_now:Nn \html { <copyrt> }
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__madyyuvi_paragraphs_seq
      { \par } {#1} % <-- split #1 at \par
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__madyyuvi_paragraphs_seq
      { \iow_now:Nn \html { <p>##1</p> } }
  }
  { \iow_now:Nn \html { </copyrt> } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\HalfTitle{Half Title}

\begin{copyrt}
\textcopyright\ Copyright text goes here

lines
\end{copyrt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice suggestion, it's working like a champ. Is it possible to omit the tags like `\vspace` `\hspace` and `\break` in the output `HTML` file? Also, advise how to output the normal paragraph into the `HTML`? Sorry for the unclear question.... Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi You have to write a command to write to the html file by hand, so by default `\vspace` will not write anything there...  If you want to _add_ something for `\vspace` then you have to redefine the command (look at the `latex.ltx` file in your TeX distribution to see the definition of `\vspace` and other commands).  Normal paragraphs will be hard because you have no control over normal typesetting.  If you want to produce html output you may want to try `tex4ht` instead.