# Expand after all that stuff?

Tags: macros, expansion

Often I find myself in the need of expanding some macro, whose contents should be given as an argument to another command. The usual solution is to invoke some [`\expandafter` concoctions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/why-do-we-need-eleven-expandafters-to-expand-four-tokens-in-the-right-order) to somehow control the expansion, but I wonder if (at least for some common cases) there is an easier way.

As an example, imagine that I want to write something like the following

```
\somecommand{Some Argument}{\secondarg}
```

But I want to expand `\secondarg` *before* actually attempting to process `\somecommand`.

For this kind of scenarions, would it be possible to define a command so that

```
\expandafterallthat{\somecommand{Some Argument}}{\secondarg}
```

expands to something like

```
\somecommand{SomeArgument}{Contents of secondarg macro}
```

Comment: I think either `etoolbox` or `etextools` provides some macros like this. I think it is the latter.

Comment: FWIW, ConTeXt has `\expanded` macro which does exactly what is being asked in the question.

Comment: Related question, [How do I have to invoke \expandafter for a macro with multiple arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133753/how-do-i-have-to-invoke-expandafter-for-a-macro-with-multiple-arguments) -- which mentions `\ExpandArgs` in newer versions

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is provided by `etextools` as `\expandnext`:

```
\usepackage{etextools}
\expandnext{\somecommand{Some Argument}}{\secondarg}
```

But if you only like to expand the second argument once you can use a double argument swapping, a trick I use in some of my packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Implementation
\def\myswap#1#2{#2{#1}}

\def\expandafterallthat#1#2{%
    \expandafter\myswap\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Test case:
%
\makeatletter
\def\somecommand#1#2{%
    \def\first{#1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\first
    \par\texttt{First argument: \first}%
    \def\second{#2}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\second
    \par\texttt{Second argument: \second}%
}
\makeatother

\def\secondarg{\empty Some stuff\empty}

\begin{document}

\expandafterallthat{\somecommand{\empty Some Argument\empty}}{\secondarg}

\end{document}
```

This correctly prints: (the `\empty`s are to see if the argument got expanded further)

```
first argument: \empty Some Argument\empty
Second argument: \empty Some stuff\empty
```

Comment: This is nice! I'm now having a look at `etextools`, seems very useful!

Answer (score 15):

Written without a package

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\expandafterallthat[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafterallthataux\expandafter{\romannumeral -`0#2 }{#1}%
}
\newcommand\expandafterallthataux[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\somecommand[2]{\detokenize{#1:::#2}}
\newcommand\secondarg{\thirdarg}
\newcommand\thirdarg{\fourtharg}
\newcommand\fourtharg{example}
\begin{document}
\expandafterallthat{\somecommand{Some Argument}}{\secondarg}

\end{document}
```

will multiply-expand input. (You don't say whether to expand `#2` once or several times.)

---

With the latest engine releases (MiKTeX or upcoming TL'19), one can use `\expanded`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\expandafterallthat[2]{%
  \expanded{\unexpanded{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\somecommand[2]{\detokenize{#1:::#2}}
\newcommand\secondarg{\thirdarg}
\newcommand\thirdarg{\fourtharg}
\newcommand\fourtharg{example}
\begin{document}
\expandafterallthat{\somecommand{Some Argument}}{\secondarg}
\end{document}
```

(`\expanded` has always been in LuaTeX, so you can test there even without the latest updated engines.)

Comment: Just seeing now that my added solution is the almost the same as yours. (I really should use `\detokenize` more often; I still use `\@onelevel@sanitize`!). The second argument should actually only be expanded once, i.e. contain `\thirdarg`, shouldn't it? If not, then the \romannumeral` trick is nice1

Comment: @Martin From the context in the question I was not sure, so I've gone for full expansion. (The `\detokenize` here is just a nice way to show quickly what the macro received.)

Comment: Why does ``\romannumeral-`0`` still expands afterwards, but does not actually consume following numbers? I thought if `#2` would start with numbers these would be consumed, but then figured that `\`0` actually already provides a full number (ASCII code of character `0`). But why is it still expanding, i.e. in look-for-a-number mode?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer You see the same for `\number`. Try for example ``\def\test{1}\detokenize\expandafter{\number-`0\test}``. I've never been quite clear *why*, but as it works ...

Comment: @Martin, @Joseph: TeX is looking for an optional space.

Answer (score 10):

Since Joseph did not mention `expl3` yet, let me do that: the LaTeX3 bundle includes a module for expansion control, `l3expan`. In particular, this includes functions to expand arguments of a command, of the form `\exp_args:N...` where the dots are letters corresponding to how the various arguments should be treated.

Many letters are in use: `n` for a brace group which should be passed with no modification, `o` to expand once, `f` to expand fully from the left, stopping at the first non-expandable token, `x` to expand fully throughout, like in an `\edef`. There is also `N` for a single non-braced token which should be passed as is, `c` for text that should be made into a control sequence, then treated as an `N` argument, and `V` and `v` for variables (see the l3expan documentation for details).

Here, you want to expand the second argument once, and leave the first unchanged, so the variant you need is `\exp_args:Nno`: leave the function unchanged (`N`), the first argument, braced, unchanged (`n`), and the second expanded once (`o`).

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{\showtokens{#1... #2}}
\newcommand{\sometext}{Some text.}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:Nno \foo {\error} {\sometext}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: And to extend the example, if you wanted to recursively expand \sometext as in Joseph's answer, you'd use \exp_args:Nnx instead.

Comment: Actually, you'd want `\exp_args:Nnf` to get the same effect as my answer :-).

Answer (score 2):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, tricky argument expansion can be replaced with intuitive function composition, which is similar to other programmming languages such as `Lua`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional}
\Functional{scoping=true} % make every function become a group

\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \SomeFunction { m m m } {
  \TlLog {#1}
  \TlLog {#2}
  \TlLog {#3}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\newcommand\secondarg{Second Argument}
\newcommand\thirdarg{Third Argument}

\SomeFunction{First Argument}{\Value\secondarg}{\Value\thirdarg}

\end{document}
```

In the above code, `\Value` is a predefined function. And the result in the log file is the following:

```
> First Argument.
> Second Argument.
> Third Argument.
```