# Use \csname ... \endcsname to compute the starred-version of some command

Tags: tex-core, expansion, starred-version

I want to define some commands declaring paired delimiters using the `mathtools` package in LaTeX. For example, `\paren{...}` should result in `\left(...\right)`, whereas `\paren[Big]{...}` should give `\Bigl(...\Bigr)`.

The command `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` almost does the job, but I would have to write `\paren*{...}` instead of `\paren{...}` in order to get `\left(...\right)`. So I added the following macro to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ifthen}
...
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclarePairedDelimiterY}[3]{%
    \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname#1Temp\endcsname{#2}{#3}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[2][leftright]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{leftright}}%
        {\csname#1Temp*\endcsname{##2}}%
        {%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{normal}}{\csname#1Temp\endcsname{##2}}{}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{big}}{\csname#1Temp\endcsname[\big]{##2}}{}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{Big}}{\csname#1Temp\endcsname[\Big]{##2}}{}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{bigg}}{\csname#1Temp\endcsname[\bigg]{##2}}{}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{Bigg}}{\csname#1Temp\endcsname[\Bigg]{##2}}{}%
        }%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

This means, there is an additional command, e.g. `\parenTemp`, which is defined by the macro `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. The desired commands, e.g. `\paren`, are then given by

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{paren}{(}{)}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{brac}{[}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{set}{\{}{\}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

While the forms `\paren[big]{...}`, `\abs[Bigg]{...}` etc. are working, `\paren{...}` just gives `...` instead of `\left(...\right)`. So the error in the code is probably in the line

```
        {\csname#1Temp*\endcsname{##2}}%
```

which is supposed to expand as `\#1Temp*{##2}`, e.g. `\parenTemp*{##2}`.

Do you have an idea what is going wrong?

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Tsuyoshi Ito's answer and [this piece of information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22288/expand-after-all-that-stuff/22292#22292), I was able to optimize the above code:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etextools}
\usepackage{ifthen}
...
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\DeclarePairedDelimiterCase}[2]{%
        \newcommand#1[1][]{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{normal}}%
            {#2}%
            {%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{big}\OR\equal{##1}{Big}\OR\equal{##1}{bigg}\OR\equal{##1}{Bigg}}%
                {\expandnext{#2[}{\csname##1\endcsname}]}%
                {#2*}%        % standard case using \left and \right
            }%
        }%
    }
    \newcommand{\DeclarePairedDelimiterY}[4][Temp]{%
        \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname#2#1\endcsname{#3}{#4}%
        \expandnext{\expandnext{\DeclarePairedDelimiterCase}{\csname#2\endcsname}}{\csname#2#1\endcsname}%
    }
    \newcommand{\DeclarePairedDelimiterXY}[6][Temp]{%
        \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\csname#2#1\endcsname[#3]{#4}{#5}{#6}%
        \expandnext{\expandnext{\DeclarePairedDelimiterCase}{\csname#2\endcsname}}{\csname#2#1\endcsname}%
    }
\makeatother
```

This new version has the following advantages:

- Users may choose the suffix of the "temporary" command on their own; default: Temp.
- Supports both `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` AND `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`.

Usage:

- `\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{name}{leftDelim}{rightDelim}` instead of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\name}{leftDelim}{rightDelim}`
- `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXY{name}{N_args}{leftDelim}{rightDelim}{code}` instead of `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\name}[N_args]{leftDelim}{rightDelim}{code}`

Note that the old version returned `{}` if `\name` was called with a misspelled optional argument. Instead, the new version then gives the "`\left...\right`-case".

Comment: Has anyone already asked the mathtools' maintainers to include this in the package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you have to write `\csname#1Temp\endcsname*` instead of `\csname#1Temp*\endcsname`.  In other words, the star should not be part of a control sequence.

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot :-)

I've tried many different alternatives but never changed the position of the star.

Comment: @wueaul: In (La)TeX, the `*` is never part of the actual command name, but is read as an argument (see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=cmdstar).

Comment: As @Caramdir said, the `*` is not part of the macro name, but read as a form of optional argument (mostly using `\@ifstar`). However, it is part of the environment name for starred environments. Not that environments are defines using macros with the same name (env `foo` => `\foo` ... `\endfoo`), so there are in fact some macros which have the star as part of there names.